# Generating strings with # number of characters

Tags: javascript, string

Is there way of generating a string made up of 250 underscores, without using a loop?
I want to avoid writing code like this:

```
var myString= '';
for (var i=0; i < 250; i++) {
    myString += '_';
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeat String - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in solution but the question [Repeat String - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript) has a nice solution:

If you don't want to alter the String prototype you can just do:

```
var num = 250;
var myChar = '_';
var myString = new Array(num + 1).join(myChar);
```

This is creating an array of 251 undefineds an then joining them by your character.
Since undefined is '' (empty string) when converted to a string in `.join()`, this gives you the string you're after.

Comment: actually, `undefined` converted to string is `"undefined"` and not the empty string; that `undefined` and `null` entries of the arry will be converted to `""` is particular to `join()`

Comment: Wow, this is probably one of the most convoluted ways to create a string that only contains a single repeating character.

Comment: @Bombe: using arrays as string builders isn't uncommon, so it's not really that far fetched...

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit of a hack, but you could do something like:

```
var arr = new Array(251);
var lineStr = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a constant that is longer that the longest number of underscores and use `substring()` to get as many as you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
```

Why do you want to generate it? And why do you want to avoid a `for` loop?

Comment: Because the string size can vary on different occasions. I was sure there was an easier approach, something like: var myString = new char('_', 250); or something similar?

Comment: Write a method that accepts the string size n and returns a string of n underscores. Because a for loop is the most straight forward and AFAIK, the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function which creates the string in (more or less) logarithmic runtime:

```
function repeat(string, times) {
    if(!(times = +times)) return ''; // convert to number; check for NaN, 0
    var result = '' + string, i = 1;
    for(; i * 2 <= times; i *= 2) result += result;
    for(; i < times; ++i) result += string;
    return result;
}

var u250 = repeat('_', 250);
```

Hopefully, I didn't mess up the loop conditions ;)

Also, [Aaron's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458972/generating-strings-with-number-of-characters/1459000#1459000) can be automated:

```
function underscores(count) {
    while(count > underscores.buffer.length)
        underscores.buffer += underscores.buffer;
    return underscores.buffer.substring(0, count);
}
underscores.buffer = '_';

var u250 = underscores(250);
```