# Is there a JavaScript function that can pad a string to get to a determined length?

Tags: javascript, string

I am in need of a JavaScript function which can take a value and pad it to a given length (I need spaces, but anything would do). I found this, but I have no idea what the heck it is doing and it doesn't seem to work for me.

```js
String.prototype.pad = function(l, s, t) {
  return s || (s = " "),
    (l -= this.length) > 0 ?
    (s = new Array(Math.ceil(l / s.length) + 1).join(s))
    .substr(0, t = !t ? l : t == 1 ?
      0 :
      Math.ceil(l / 2)) + this + s.substr(0, l - t) :
    this;
};



var s = "Jonas";
document.write(
  '<h2>S = '.bold(), s, "</h2>",
  'S.pad(20, "[]", 0) = '.bold(), s.pad(20, "[]", 0), "<br />",
  'S.pad(20, "[====]", 1) = '.bold(), s.pad(20, "[====]", 1), "<br />",
  'S.pad(20, "~", 2) = '.bold(), s.pad(20, "~", 2)
);
```

Comment: "Jonas".padStart(7, " ") https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36503658/157247) with the standard, now-built-in `padStart` and `padEnd` should be the accepted one now. (Present in all major browsers; IE11 or even earlier can be polyfilled.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry to bother you, I use node.js on a server (like, a ubuntu server) and I don't know how to use .padEnd() etc; they are unevailable when I try. Can you help?  :O  :O  TY  :)

Comment: @Fattie - Sounds like you're using a really old version of Node.js. `padEnd` was added in ES2017, so Node.js has had it for over six years. The oldest version I have handy to check is v10.20.1, and even it has `padEnd`. Try `node --version` to see what version you have. The current LTS is v20.11.1, cutting edge is v21.6.2.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're amazing.  Your info was key. Also, as a Swift programmer :) I realized I was foolishly using `.padEnd` on an undefined (I failed to read the clear error message). Thank you so much !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 622, accepted):

[ECMAScript 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#8th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2017) (ES8) added [`String.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) (along with [`String.padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)) for just this purpose:

```
"Jonas".padStart(10); // Default pad string is a space
"42".padStart(6, "0"); // Pad with "0"
"*".padStart(8, "-/|\\"); // produces '-/|\\-/|*'
```

If not present in the JavaScript host, `String.padStart` can be added as a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)).

### Pre ES8

I found this solution [here](http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2010/07/20/little-tricks-string-padding-in-javascript/) and this is for me much much simpler:

```
var n = 123

String("00000" + n).slice(-5); // returns 00123
("00000" + n).slice(-5); // returns 00123
("     " + n).slice(-5); // returns "  123" (with two spaces)
```

And here I made an extension to the string object:

```
String.prototype.paddingLeft = function (paddingValue) {
   return String(paddingValue + this).slice(-paddingValue.length);
};
```

An example to use it:

```
function getFormattedTime(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();

  hours = hours.toString().paddingLeft("00");
  minutes = minutes.toString().paddingLeft("00");

  return "{0}:{1}".format(hours, minutes);
};

String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number] : match;
    });
};
```

This will return a time in the format "15:30".

Comment: Easily the most readable and concise approach I've found; simple enough that I generally wouldn't even bother with the prototype extension (at least for only a few uses in an app). Well done.

Comment: Be aware, this solution will shorten strings that are longer than the slice argument (i.e. 5 chars here).

Comment: Great solution. However, as Denis mentions this will truncate the number when greater than the paddingValue. Can easily fix this with slicing the greater of the two. E.g. return String(paddingValue + this).slice(-1 * Math.max(this.length, paddingValue.length)); };

Comment: Hi Yaniv. You have a very good suggestion to modify the algorithm. However, in my case, the requirements always precede this problem because when I try to format something, I always have a minimum of specifications about the value that I have to treat and in this case, the specifications will correct this problem. As example, if I have a phone number to format and I only handle phone in Canada, I will validate that the phone number have 10 characters before formatting it. In any cases, your solution is great too. :)

Comment: If you are doing this a lot (e.g. padding a long list of values in a list of some sort on your page or other application) also see the answer with a **A faster method** at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng/24398129#24398129

Comment: This badly needs to be updated to use the JS `String`  libs `String.padStart()` and `String.padEnd()` for left/right padding.

Comment: `String.padStart()` and `String.padEnd()` are great but as a note they're [not supported by IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pad-start-end).

Answer (score 132):

## A faster method

If you are doing this repeatedly, for example to pad values in an array, and performance is a factor, the following approach can give you nearly a **100x advantage** in speed ([jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/string-padding-performance)) over other solution that are currently discussed on the inter webs. The basic idea is that you are providing the pad function with a fully padded empty string to use as a buffer. The pad function just appends to string to be added to this pre-padded string (one string concat) and then slices or trims the result to the desired length.

```
function pad(pad, str, padLeft) {
  if (typeof str === 'undefined') 
    return pad;
  if (padLeft) {
    return (pad + str).slice(-pad.length);
  } else {
    return (str + pad).substring(0, pad.length);
  }
}
```

For example, to zero pad a number to a length of 10 digits,

```
pad('0000000000',123,true);
```

To pad a string with whitespace, so the entire string is 255 characters,

```
var padding = Array(256).join(' '), // make a string of 255 spaces
pad(padding,123,true);
```

#### Performance Test

See the *jsPerf* test [here](http://jsperf.com/string-padding-performance).

And this is faster than ES6 `string.repeat` by 2x as well, as shown by the revised JsPerf [here](http://jsperf.com/string-padding-performance/7)

### Please note that `jsPerf` is no longer online

Please note that the jsPerf site that we originally used to benchmark the various methods is no longer online. Unfortunately, this means we can't get to those test results. Sad but true.

Comment: +1 Part of my issue with StackOverflow is the inability for moderators to change votes based off answers that are clearly superior. This is one of those cases.

Comment: As someone else proved out in a later jsPerf (links added above), this approach is ~ 2x faster than the ES6 `string.repeat` method. So if you are doing a lot of string padding, definitely try this.

Comment: I am confused by Jason's comment – how is this answer different from the accepted?

Comment: I looked at your jsPerf.  Those tests are for your function and something that uses a while() loop, which no other high-rated answer uses.  I'm not sure that means it's faster?

Comment: My only observation with this approach is, if the actual `str` length is grater than the `pad` length, then the output will be chopped at the end. Meaning that `str` will be returned to the length of `pad`. This may not be the intended or expected behavior.

Answer (score 66):

`String.prototype.padStart()` and `String.prototype.padEnd()` are currently TC39 candidate proposals: see [github.com/tc39/proposal-string-pad-start-end](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-pad-start-end) (only available in Firefox as of April 2016; a [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-pad-start-end/blob/master/polyfill.js) is available).

Comment: Supported by all (modern) browsers now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Browser_compatibility

Comment: For the lazy: `myString.padStart(padLength [, padString])` and `myString.padEnd(padLength [, padString])`

Comment: Please add some example usage, now that this has been supported by all modern browsers. This should be encouraged.

Comment: Holy crap, how have I not heard of this until today?? _This_ should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 47):

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript_pad.html

```
/**
*
*  JavaScript string pad
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var STR_PAD_LEFT = 1;
var STR_PAD_RIGHT = 2;
var STR_PAD_BOTH = 3;

function pad(str, len, pad, dir) {

    if (typeof(len) == "undefined") { var len = 0; }
    if (typeof(pad) == "undefined") { var pad = ' '; }
    if (typeof(dir) == "undefined") { var dir = STR_PAD_RIGHT; }

    if (len + 1 >= str.length) {

        switch (dir){

            case STR_PAD_LEFT:
                str = Array(len + 1 - str.length).join(pad) + str;
            break;

            case STR_PAD_BOTH:
                var padlen = len - str.length;
                var right = Math.ceil( padlen / 2 );
                var left = padlen - right;
                str = Array(left+1).join(pad) + str + Array(right+1).join(pad);
            break;

            default:
                str = str + Array(len + 1 - str.length).join(pad);
            break;

        } // switch

    }

    return str;
}
```

It's a lot more readable.

Comment: Does not seem to work when pad is a space: `pad("hello", 20) = "hello "`

Answer (score 46):

Here's a recursive approach to it.

```
function pad(width, string, padding) { 
  return (width <= string.length) ? string : pad(width, padding + string, padding)
}
```

An example...

```
pad(5, 'hi', '0')
=> "000hi"
```

Comment: there's also a recursive definition of integer multiplication... always remember there's a 'curse' in recursive...

Comment: There's also narwhals and a drunk guy down the street, but neither are relevant. The curse of recursion only applies when a programmer doesn't know when its appropriate.

Comment: "The curse of recursion only applies when a programmer doesn't know when its appropriate" Or when they don't realize it is inappropriate.  Such as for a simple string pad function.

Comment: This is pretty elegant and worked perfectly for my use case. If you need to pad spaces to align text, just throw in the length of the longest string =)

Comment: It is elegant, but it also creates a new string on each iteration of the function. This function is O(n) while the most popular solution by @Samuel is O(1). Both are elegant, but one is vastly more efficient. That said, it's a neat approach, and might be even faster in a different language.

Comment: Add 'string = string.toString();' to the function for when you pass it an integer.

Comment: imho, that should be the chosen answer

Comment: You could eaisly avoid recursion by using `while`. And make it faster by saving padded string... E.g.: https://gist.github.com/Eccenux/52062de47b11cd79ffb0f2c7995dc0f3

Answer (score 44):

ECMAScript 2017 adds a padStart method to the String prototype. This method will pad a string with spaces to a given length. This method also takes an optional string that will be used instead of spaces for padding.

```
'abc'.padStart(10);         // "       abc"
'abc'.padStart(10, "foo");  // "foofoofabc"
'abc'.padStart(6,"123465"); // "123abc"
'abc'.padStart(8, "0");     // "00000abc"
'abc'.padStart(1);          // "abc"
```

A padEnd method was also added that works in the same manner.

For browser compatibility (and a useful polyfill) see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Comment: **Best answer  HERE** for nowadays! 2019!

Answer (score 23):

Using the [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) method [String#repeat](http://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-string.prototype.repeat), a pad function is as simple as:

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function(char, length) {
    return char.repeat(Math.max(0, length - this.length)) + this;
}
```

`String#repeat` is currently supported in Firefox and Chrome only. for other implementation, one might consider the following simple [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)):

```
String.prototype.repeat = String.prototype.repeat || function(n){
    return n<=1 ? this : (this + this.repeat(n-1));
}
```

Comment: For those working in Node.js, String.repeat is also supported there.

Answer (score 17):

Using the ECMAScript 6 method [String#repeat](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.repeat) and [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), a pad function is as simple as:

```
var leftPad = (s, c, n) => c.repeat(n - s.length) + s;
leftPad("foo", "0", 5); //returns "00foo"
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fad0wp4)

**edit:**
suggestion from the comments:

```
const leftPad = (s, c, n) => n - s.length > 0 ? c.repeat(n - s.length) + s : s;
```

this way, it wont throw an error when `s.length`is greater than `n`

**edit2:**
suggestion from the comments:

```
const leftPad = (s, c, n) =>{ s = s.toString(); c = c.toString(); return s.length > n ? s : c.repeat(n - s.length) + s; }
```

this way, you can use the function for strings and non-strings alike.

Comment: This is nice, but if `s.length` is greater than `n` it will throw. Suggest: `let leftPad = (s, c, n) => n - s.length > 0 ? c.repeat(n - s.length) + s : s;`

Comment: it doesn't work for non-strings. As in `leftPad(12, ' ', 5)` . While I know strictly speaking that might be ok it's probably one of the most common use cases (padding numbers). Maybe `function leftPad(s, c, n) { s = s.toString(); return s.length > len ? s : c.repeat(n - s.length) + s; }`. Using `function` means leftPad can be at the bottom of the file. Otherwise you should arguably use `const` not `var` nor `let`.

Comment: @gman thanks for this suggestion, but what is your variable `len`?

Comment: Doh, `len` should be `n`

Answer (score 14):

The key trick in both those solutions is to create an `array` instance with a given size (one more than the desired length), and then to immediately call the `join()` method to make a `string`. The `join()` method is passed the padding `string` (spaces probably). Since the `array` is empty, the empty cells will be rendered as empty `strings` during the process of joining the `array` into one result `string`, and only the padding will remain. It's a really nice technique.

Answer (score 12):

With ES8, there are two options for padding.

You can check them in the documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 10):

**Pad with default values**

I noticed that I mostly need the padLeft for time conversion / number padding.

So I wrote this function:

```
function padL(a, b, c) { // string/number, length=2, char=0
  return (new Array(b || 2).join(c || 0) + a).slice(-b)
}
```

This simple function supports **Number** or **String** as input.

The default pad is two characters.

The default char is 0.

So I can simply write:

```
padL(1);
// 01
```

If I add the second argument (pad width):

```
padL(1, 3);
// 001
```

The third parameter (pad character)

```
padL('zzz', 10, 'x');
// xxxxxxxzzz
```

@BananaAcid: If you pass a undefined value or a 0 length string, you get `0undefined`, so:

As suggested

```
function padL(a, b, c) { // string/number, length=2, char=0
  return (new Array((b || 1) + 1).join(c || 0) + (a || '')).slice(-(b || 2))
}
```

But this can also be achieved in a shorter way.

```
function padL(a, b, c) { // string/number, length=2, char=0
  return (new Array(b || 2).join(c || 0) + (a || c || 0)).slice(-b)
}
```

It also works with:

```
padL(0)
padL(NaN)
padL('')
padL(undefined)
padL(false)
```

And if you want to be able to pad in both ways:

```
function pad(a, b, c, d) { // string/number, length=2, char=0, 0/false=Left-1/true=Right
  return a = (a || c || 0), c = new Array(b || 2).join(c || 0), d ? (a + c).slice(0, b) : (c + a).slice(-b)
}
```

which can be written in a shorter way without using slice.

```
function pad(a, b, c, d) {
  return a = (a || c || 0) + '', b = new Array((++b || 3) - a.length).join(c || 0), d ? a+b : b+a
}
/*

Usage:

pad(
 input // (int or string) or undefined, NaN, false, empty string
       // default:0 or PadCharacter
 // Optional
 ,PadLength // (int) default:2
 ,PadCharacter // (string or int) default:'0'
 ,PadDirection // (bolean) default:0 (padLeft) - (true or 1) is padRight
)

*/
```

Now if you try to pad 'averylongword' with 2... that’s not my problem.

---

I said that I would give you a tip.

Most of the time, if you pad, you do it for the same value N times.

Using any type of function inside a loop slows down the loop!!!

So if you just want to pad left some numbers inside a long list, don't use functions to do this simple thing.

Use something like this:

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    paddedArray = [],
    len = arrayOfNumbers.length;
while(len--) {
  paddedArray[len] = ('0000' + arrayOfNumbers[len]).slice(-4);
}
```

If you don't know how the maximum padding size based on the numbers inside the array.

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 49095],
    paddedArray = [],
    len = arrayOfNumbers.length;

// Search the highest number
var arrayMax = Function.prototype.apply.bind(Math.max, null),
// Get that string length
padSize = (arrayMax(arrayOfNumbers) + '').length,
// Create a Padding string
padStr = new Array(padSize).join(0);
// And after you have all this static values cached start the loop.
while(len--) {
  paddedArray[len] = (padStr + arrayOfNumbers[len]).slice(-padSize); // substr(-padSize)
}
console.log(paddedArray);

/*
0: "00001"
1: "00002"
2: "00003"
3: "00004"
4: "00005"
5: "00006"
6: "00007"
7: "49095"
*/
```

Comment: Very nice! Came up with the same result, just as a note: this concats the string to the maximum length given and an empty string will be one char too short and undefined str will result in 'undefined' beeing used as well as splice could throw an error -- combined. `return (new Array((b||1)+1).join(c||0)+(a||'')).slice(-(b||2))`. And as always: you guys out there, do not just copy code you do not understand.

Comment: (new Array(b||2).join(c||0)+(a||c||0)).slice(-b)...shorter

Answer (score 10):

Taking up Samuel's ideas, upward here. And remember an old SQL script, I tried with this:

```
a=1234;
'0000'.slice(a.toString().length)+a;
```

It works in all the cases I could imagine:

```
a=     1 result  0001
a=    12 result  0012
a=   123 result  0123
a=  1234 result  1234
a= 12345 result 12345
a=  '12' result  0012
```

Comment: Yes works fine with my example of: 
                           HHMM = '00'.slice((dif/60>>0).toString().length)+(dif/60>>0) + ":" + '00'.slice((dif%60).toString().length)+(dif%60)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a build in method you can use -

```
str1.padStart(2, '0')
```

Comment: yeah, 11 years ago there wasn't one but your answer is what is in the comment of my question.

Answer (score 5):

padding string has been inplemented in new javascript version.

`str.padStart(targetLength [, padString])`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart

If you want your own function check this example:

```
const myString = 'Welcome to my house';
String.prototype.padLeft = function(times = 0, str = ' ') {
    return (Array(times).join(str) + this);
}
console.log(myString.padLeft(12, ':'));
//:::::::::::Welcome to my house
```

Comment: This answer has been mentioned by multiple other answers so it's a duplicate that adds no new information. Please search before answer.

Comment: This one is the first one with the full signature. And it must be the only answer as of today.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple function that I use.

```
var pad=function(num,field){
    var n = '' + num;
    var w = n.length;
    var l = field.length;
    var pad = w < l ? l-w : 0;
    return field.substr(0,pad) + n;
};
```

For example:

```
pad    (20,'     ');    //   20
pad   (321,'     ');    //  321
pad (12345,'     ');    //12345
pad (   15,'00000');    //00015
pad (  999,'*****');    //**999
pad ('cat','_____');    //__cat
```

Answer (score 4):

A short way:

```
(x=>(new Array(int-x.length+1)).join(char)+x)(String)
```

Example:

```
(x=>(new Array(6-x.length+1)).join("0")+x)("1234")
```

return: "001234"

Comment: maybe `String.prototype.padStart()` should be easier.

Answer (score 3):

[ES7](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/) is just drafts and proposals right now, but if you wanted to track compatibility with the specification, your pad functions need:

1. Multi-character pad support.
2. Don't truncate the input string
3. Pad defaults to space

From my [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) library, but apply your own due diligence for prototype extensions.

```
// Tests
'hello'.lpad(4) === 'hello'
'hello'.rpad(4) === 'hello'
'hello'.lpad(10) === '     hello'
'hello'.rpad(10) === 'hello     '
'hello'.lpad(10, '1234') === '41234hello'
'hello'.rpad(10, '1234') === 'hello12341'

String.prototype.lpad || (String.prototype.lpad = function(length, pad)
{
    if(length < this.length)
        return this;

    pad = pad || ' ';
    let str = this;

    while(str.length < length)
    {
        str = pad + str;
    }

    return str.substr( -length );
});

String.prototype.rpad || (String.prototype.rpad = function(length, pad)
{
    if(length < this.length)
        return this;

    pad = pad || ' ';
    let str = this;

    while(str.length < length)
    {
        str += pad;
    }

    return str.substr(0, length);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple answer in basically one line of code.

```
var value = 35 // the numerical value
var x = 5 // the minimum length of the string

var padded = ("00000" + value).substr(-x);
```

Make sure the number of characters in you padding, zeros here, is at least as many as your intended minimum length. So really, to put it into one line, to get a result of "00035" in this case is:

```
var padded = ("00000" + 35).substr(-5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Array manipulations are really slow compared to simple string concat. Of course, benchmark for your use case.

```
function(string, length, pad_char, append) {
    string = string.toString();
    length = parseInt(length) || 1;
    pad_char = pad_char || ' ';

    while (string.length < length) {
        string = append ? string+pad_char : pad_char+string;
    }
    return string;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant of [@Daniel LaFavers'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903742/638546) answer.

```
var mask = function (background, foreground) {
  bg = (new String(background));
  fg = (new String(foreground));
  bgl = bg.length;
  fgl = fg.length;
  bgs = bg.substring(0, Math.max(0, bgl - fgl));
  fgs = fg.substring(Math.max(0, fgl - bgl));
  return bgs + fgs;
};
```

For example:

```
mask('00000', 11  );   // '00011'
mask('00011','00' );   // '00000'
mask( 2     , 3   );   // '3'
mask('0'    ,'111');   // '1'
mask('fork' ,'***');   // 'f***'
mask('_____','dog');   // '__dog'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's 2014, and I suggest a JavaScript string-padding function. Ha!

Bare-bones: right-pad with spaces

```
function pad (str, length) {
    var padding = (new Array(Math.max(length - str.length + 1, 0))).join(" ");
    return str + padding;
}
```

Fancy: pad with options

```
/**
 * @param {*}       str                         Input string, or any other type (will be converted to string)
 * @param {number}  length                      Desired length to pad the string to
 * @param {Object}  [opts]
 * @param {string}  [opts.padWith=" "]          Character to use for padding
 * @param {boolean} [opts.padLeft=false]        Whether to pad on the left
 * @param {boolean} [opts.collapseEmpty=false]  Whether to return an empty string if the input was empty
 * @returns {string}
 */
function pad(str, length, opts) {
    var padding = (new Array(Math.max(length - (str + "").length + 1, 0))).join(opts && opts.padWith || " "),
        collapse = opts && opts.collapseEmpty && !(str + "").length;
    return collapse ? "" : opts && opts.padLeft ? padding + str : str + padding;
}
```

Usage (fancy):

```
pad("123", 5);
// Returns "123  "

pad(123, 5);
// Returns "123  " - non-string input

pad("123", 5, { padWith: "0", padLeft: true });
// Returns "00123"

pad("", 5);
// Returns "     "

pad("", 5, { collapseEmpty: true });
// Returns ""

pad("1234567", 5);
// Returns "1234567"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind including a utility library, lodash library has [_.pad, _.padLeft and _.padRight](https://lodash.com/docs#pad) functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to avoid recursion because its costly.

```js
function padLeft(str,size,padwith) {
 if(size <= str.length) {
        // not padding is required.
  return str;
 } else {
        // 1- take array of size equal to number of padding char + 1. suppose if string is 55 and we want 00055 it means we have 3 padding char so array size should be 3 + 1 (+1 will explain below)
        // 2- now join this array with provided padding char (padwith) or default one ('0'). so it will produce '000'
        // 3- now append '000' with orginal string (str = 55), will produce 00055

        // why +1 in size of array? 
        // it is a trick, that we are joining an array of empty element with '0' (in our case)
        // if we want to join items with '0' then we should have at least 2 items in the array to get joined (array with single item doesn't need to get joined).
        // <item>0<item>0<item>0<item> to get 3 zero we need 4 (3+1) items in array   
  return Array(size-str.length+1).join(padwith||'0')+str
 }
}

alert(padLeft("59",5) + "\n" +
     padLeft("659",5) + "\n" +
     padLeft("5919",5) + "\n" +
     padLeft("59879",5) + "\n" +
     padLeft("5437899",5));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**************************************************************************************************
Pad a string to pad_length fillig it with pad_char.
By default the function performs a left pad, unless pad_right is set to true.

If the value of pad_length is negative, less than, or equal to the length of the input string, no padding takes place.
**************************************************************************************************/
if(!String.prototype.pad)
String.prototype.pad = function(pad_char, pad_length, pad_right) 
{
   var result = this;
   if( (typeof pad_char === 'string') && (pad_char.length === 1) && (pad_length > this.length) )
   {
      var padding = new Array(pad_length - this.length + 1).join(pad_char); //thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript/2433358#2433358
      result = (pad_right ? result + padding : padding + result);
   }
   return result;
}
```

And then you can do:

```
alert( "3".pad("0", 3) ); //shows "003"
alert( "hi".pad(" ", 3) ); //shows " hi"
alert( "hi".pad(" ", 3, true) ); //shows "hi "
```

Comment: Don't mess with the prototypes!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JavaScript function that adds a specified number of paddings with a custom symbol. The function takes three parameters.

```
padMe --> string or number to left pad
pads  --> number of pads
padSymble --> custom symbol, default is "0"
```

```
function leftPad(padMe, pads, padSymble) {
    if(typeof padMe === "undefined") {
        padMe = "";
    }
    if (typeof pads === "undefined") {
        pads = 0;
    }
    if (typeof padSymble === "undefined") {
        padSymble = "0";
    }

    var symble = "";
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i < pads; i++) {
       symble += padSymble;
    }
    var length = symble.length - padMe.toString().length;
    result = symble.substring(0, length);
    return result.concat(padMe.toString());
}
```

Here are some results:

```
> leftPad(1)
"1"

> leftPad(1, 4)
"0001"

> leftPad(1, 4, "0")
"0001"

> leftPad(1, 4, "@")
"@@@1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a very simple hacky one-liner to pad, just make a string of the desired padding character of the desired max padding length and then substring it to the length of what you want to pad.

Example: padding the string store in `e` with spaces to 25 characters long.

```
var e = "hello"; e = e + "                         ".substring(e.length)
```

Result: `"hello                    "`

If you want to do the same with a number as input just call `.toString()` on it before.

Comment: This is actually pretty neat, not as a general purpose function - but I could see this as a valid hack in some contexts to save a loop.

Comment: Interesting idea. @ankr To use it as a general purpose function, you could use `Array(n).join(c)` to make the padding length and padding character configurable, e.g. `Array(26).join(' ')`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another take at with combination of a couple of solutions:

```
/**
 * pad string on left
 * @param {number} number of digits to pad, default is 2
 * @param {string} string to use for padding, default is '0' *
 * @returns {string} padded string
 */
String.prototype.paddingLeft = function (b, c) {
    if (this.length > (b||2))
        return this + '';
  return (this || c || 0) + '', b = new Array((++b || 3) - this.length).join(c || 0), b + this
};

/**
 * pad string on right
 * @param {number} number of digits to pad, default is 2
 * @param {string} string to use for padding, default is '0' *
 * @returns {string} padded string
 */
String.prototype.paddingRight = function (b, c) {
  if (this.length > (b||2))
        return this + '';
  return (this||c||0) + '', b = new Array((++b || 3) - this.length).join(c || 0), this + b
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A friend asked about using a JavaScript function to pad left. It turned into a little bit of an endeavor between some of us in chat to code golf it. This was the result:

```
function l(p,t,v){
    v+="";return v.length>=t?v:l(p,t,p+v); 
}
```

It ensures that the value to be padded is a string, and then if it isn't the length of the total desired length it will pad it once and then recurse. Here is what it looks like with more logical naming and structure

```
function padLeft(pad, totalLength, value){
    value = value.toString();

    if( value.length >= totalLength ){
        return value;
    }else{
        return padLeft(pad, totalLength, pad + value);
    }
}
```

The example we were using was to ensure that numbers were padded with `0` to the left to make a max length of 6. Here is an example set:

```js
function l(p,t,v){v+="";return v.length>=t?v:l(p,t,p+v);}

var vals = [6451,123,466750];

var pad = l(0,6,vals[0]);// pad with 0's, max length 6

var pads = vals.map(function(i){ return l(0,6,i) });

document.write(pads.join("<br />"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but thought I might share anyway. I found it useful to add a prototype extension to Object. That way I can pad numbers and strings, left or right. I have a module with similar utilities I include in my scripts.

```
// include the module in your script, there is no need to export
var jsAddOns = require('<path to module>/jsAddOns');
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~ jsAddOns.js ~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
/* 
 * method prototype for any Object to pad it's toString()
 * representation with additional characters to the specified length
 *
 * @param padToLength required int
 *     entire length of padded string (original + padding)
 * @param padChar optional char
 *     character to use for padding, default is white space
 * @param padLeft optional boolean
 *     if true padding added to left
 *     if omitted or false, padding added to right
 *
 * @return padded string or
 *     original string if length is >= padToLength
 */
Object.prototype.pad = function(padToLength, padChar, padLeft) {    

    // get the string value
    s = this.toString()

    // default padToLength to 0
    // if omitted, original string is returned
    padToLength = padToLength || 0;

    // default padChar to empty space
    padChar = padChar || ' ';


    // ignore padding if string too long
    if (s.length >= padToLength) {
        return s;
    }

    // create the pad of appropriate length
    var pad = Array(padToLength - s.length).join(padChar);

    // add pad to right or left side
    if (padLeft) {
        return pad  + s;        
    } else {
        return s + pad;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Never insert data somewhere (especially not at beginning, like `str = pad + str;`), since the data will be reallocated everytime. Append always at end!
2. Don't pad your string in the loop. Leave it alone and build your pad string first. In the end concatenate it with your main string.
3. Don't assign padding string each time (like `str += pad;`). It is much faster to append the padding string to itself and extract first x-chars (the parser can do this efficiently if you extract from first char). This is exponential growth, which means that it wastes some memory temporarily (you should not do this with extremely huge texts).

```js
if (!String.prototype.lpad) {
    String.prototype.lpad = function(pad, len) {
        while (pad.length < len) {
            pad += pad;
        }
        return pad.substr(0, len-this.length) + this;
    }
}

if (!String.prototype.rpad) {
    String.prototype.rpad = function(pad, len) {
        while (pad.length < len) {
            pad += pad;
        }
        return this + pad.substr(0, len-this.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

I'm not so sure about its performance, but I find it much more readable than other options I saw around here...

```
var replicate = function(len, char) {
  return Array(len + 1).join(char || ' ');
};

var padr = function(text, len, char) {
  if (text.length >= len)
    return text;
  return text + replicate(len-text.length, char);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. function

   ```
   var _padLeft = function(paddingString, width, replacementChar) {
       return paddingString.length >= width ? paddingString : _padLeft(replacementChar + paddingString, width, replacementChar || ' ');
   };
   ```
2. String prototype

   ```
   String.prototype.padLeft = function(width, replacementChar) {
           return this.length >= width ? this.toString() : (replacementChar + this).padLeft(width, replacementChar || ' ');
   };
   ```
3. slice

   ```
   ('00000' + paddingString).slice(-5)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the best answers of this question I have made a prototype for **String** called padLeft (*exactly like we have in C#*):

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function (paddingChar, totalWidth) {
    if (this.toString().length >= totalWidth)
        return this.toString();

    var array = new Array(totalWidth); 

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = paddingChar;

    return (array.join("") + this.toString()).slice(-array.length);
}
```

Usage:

```
var str = "12345";
console.log(str.padLeft("0", 10)); //Result is: "0000012345"
```

[JsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RE7n2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function(pad) {
        var s = Array.apply(null, Array(pad)).map(function() { return "0"; }).join('') + this;
        return s.slice(-1 * Math.max(this.length, pad));
    };
```

usage:

1. `"123".padLeft(2)` returns: `"123"`
2. `"12".padLeft(2)` returns: `"12"`
3. `"1".padLeft(2)` returns: `"01"`

Answer (score 0):

All options included

```
function padding(stringToBePadded, paddingCharacter, totalLength, padLeftElseRight){
    //will pad any string provided in first argument, with padding character provide in 2nd argument and truncate to lenght provided in third argument, padding left if 4th argument true or undefined, right if false. 
    // i.e. padding("lode","x","10")  -->  "xxxxxxlode"
    // i.e. padding("lode","x","10",true)  -->  "xxxxxxlode"
    // i.e. padding("lode","x","10",false)  -->  "lodexxxxxx"
    // i.e. padding("12","0","5")  -->  "00012"
    {
        padLeftElseRight = typeof padLeftElseRight !== 'undefined' ? padLeftElseRight : true;
    }
    if (stringToBePadded.length > totalLength){
        // console.log("string too long to be padded");
        return stringToBePadded;
    }
    var paddingString = paddingCharacter.repeat(totalLength);//make long string of padding characters
    if ( padLeftElseRight){
        return String(paddingString+stringToBePadded).slice(-totalLength);
    }else{ 
        return String(stringToBePadded+paddingString).slice(0,totalLength); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this in case you ever need to pad with multiple characters or tags (e.g. `&nbsp;`) for display:

```
$.padStringLeft = function(s, pad, len) {
    if(typeof s !== 'undefined') {
        var c=s.length; while(len > c) {s=pad+s;c++;}
    }
    return s;
}    

$.padStringRight = function(s, pad, len) {
    if(typeof s !== 'undefined') {
        var c=s.length; while(len > c) {s += pad;c++;}
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my combination of aboves solutions added to my own, always evolving version :)

```
//in preperation for ES6
String.prototype.lpad || (String.prototype.lpad = function( length, charOptional )
{
    if (length <= this.length) return this;
    return ( new Array((length||0)+1).join(String(charOptional)||' ') + (this||'') ).slice( -(length||0) );
});


'abc'.lpad(5,'.') == '..abc'
String(5679).lpad(10,0) == '0000005679'
String().lpad(4,'-') == '----' // repeat string
```

Answer (score 0):

use repeat, it would be more simple.

```
    var padLeft=function(str, pad, fw){
        return fw>str.length ? pad.repeat(fw-str.length)+str : str;
    }
```

you can use it like:
 padeLeft('origin-str', '0', 20)

Answer (score 0):

One liner if you want something compact:

```js
String.prototype.pad = function(len, chr){
        return((((new Array(len)).fill(chr)).join("") +this).substring(this.length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my version of function:

```
function str_pad(str, size, char, right) {
    var s = str + "";
    while (s.length < size) {
        if (right) {
            s = s + char;
        } else {
            s = char + s;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I might create a one-line function at the point where it is needed:

```
var padleft = (s,c,len) => { while(s.length < len) s = c + s; return s; }
```

Example:

```
> console.log( padleft( '110', '0', 8) );
> 00000110
```

Answer (score 0):

### The incredibly simple way to right pad a string,

say max length ten, is

```
name = (name + "                    ").substring(0,10)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function leftPad(number) {
    return (number < 9) ? '0' + number : number;
}

// Call it like this
var month = 3;
month = leftPad(month); // Output: month=04
```

Answer (score -1):

Like PHP:

```
const STR_PAD_RIGHT = 1;
const STR_PAD_LEFT = 0;
const STR_PAD_BOTH = 2;

/**
 * @see http://php.net/str_pad
 * @param mixed input 
 * @param integer length 
 * @param string string 
 * @param integer type 
 * @return string
 */
function str_pad(input, length, string, type) {
    if (type === undefined || (type !== STR_PAD_LEFT && type !== STR_PAD_BOTH)) {
        type = STR_PAD_RIGHT
    }

    if (input.toString().length >= length) {
         return input;
    } else {
        if (type === STR_PAD_BOTH) {
            input = (string + input + string);
        } else if (type == STR_PAD_LEFT) {
            input = (string + input);
        } else {
            input = (input + string);
        }

        return str_pad(input.toString(), length, string, type);
    }
}
```