# Simplest inline method to left pad a string

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a JavaScript function that can pad a string to get to a determined length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng)

What's the simplest way to left pad a string in javascript?

I'm looking for an inline expression equivalent to `mystr.lpad("0", 4)`: for `mystr='45'` would return `0045`.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Found a simple one line solution:

```
("0000" + n).slice(-4)
```

If the string and padding are in variables, you would have:

```
mystr = '45'
pad = '0000'
(pad + mystr).slice(-pad.length)
```

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744576/959570), thanks to @dani-p.
Credits to @profitehlolz.

Comment: Nice one liner but breaks when the string is longer than the padding.

Comment: Use this if mystr could be longer than the pad string and you don't want mystr to be truncated.
(pad + mystr).slice(-Math.max(pad.length, mystr.length))

Comment: or using `.substr()` instead of array.slice(), borrowing from mogsdad on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366849/convert-1-to-0001-in-javascript `('0000'+str).substring(Math.min((""+str).length,4))`

Comment: '01'.padStart(4).replace(' ',0)

Comment: `'01'.padStart(4).replaceAll(' ',0)`  otherwise will return "0 01".  And actually can now just use `'01'.padStart(4, "0")`

Answer (score 22):

```
function pad(value, length) {
    return (value.toString().length < length) ? pad("0"+value, length):value;
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution. One suggestion: this function can return a number instead of a string if in the first call to the function a number is passed to value, and value.toString().length < length. A simple fix would be:

code
return (value.toString().length < length ? pad("0"+value, length) : value.toString()

Comment: You forgot to reduce length by 1 when recursing.

Comment: @VickyChijwani Could you explain a little more about why that would benefit this solution?

Comment: Well, won't the function go into an infinite loop if `length` never reaches 0? Which means it must be decreased by at least 1 in every call to `pad()`.

Comment: @KevinBowersox sorry, my bad, length does not need to reach 0 because the termination condition is `value.toString().length < length` and `value` grows by 1 in every call.

Answer (score 10):

Something like below:

```
String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str = this;
    while (str.length < length)
        str = padString + str;
    return str;
}
console.log('45'.lpad('0', 4)); // "0045"
```

Comment: +1. But appeding data to the beginning is never a good idea. The data will then have to be reallocated everytime. Instead, append always to the end only. Following small improvement is ~3 times faster:
`String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str='';
    while (str.length < length) {
        str += padString;
    }
    return this + str;
}`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: It should be `return str + this;`. Alternatively, I have posted an even more optimized and faster version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39030416/1854856