# Variable inside Array() is undefined

Tags: javascript, padleft

I'm having a problem with an undefined variable error. This is my code:

```
window.sys.Bash = {};
window.sys.Bash.version = "";
window.sys.Bash.version.major = 0;
window.sys.Bash.version.minor = 1;
window.sys.Bash.version.build = 1;
window.sys.Bash.version.release = "beta";
window.sys.Bash.printing = false;
window.sys.Bash.queue = Array();
window.sys.Bash.span = bash;
window.sys.Bash.span.input = input;

window.sys.Bash.version = ""
    + window.sys.Bash.version.major + "."
    + window.sys.Bash.version.minor + "."
    + Array(2-window.sys.Bash.version.build.toString().length+1).join('0')
    + window.sys.Bash.version.build + "-"
    + window.sys.Bash.version.release + " "
    + "(x86_64-" + window.sys.platform + ")";

delete bash; delete input;
```

My Web console says, that window.sys.Bash.version.build is undefined on this line:

```
    + Array(2-window.sys.Bash.version.build.toString().length+1).join('0')
```

I copied the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367656/1137334), so I don't know much about it, but it should work, huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `version` as primitive, rather than object. Try this:

```
window.sys.Bash.version = {};
window.sys.Bash.version.major = 0;
window.sys.Bash.version.minor = 1;
window.sys.Bash.version.build = 1;
```

Adding properties to primitive is not an error, but the properties will be added to a temporary object that is then lost. Basically, this happened:

```
window.sys.Bash.version = "";
new String(window.sys.Bash.version).major = 0;
new String(window.sys.Bash.version).minor = 1;
new String(window.sys.Bash.version).build = 1;
```

This is described [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2):

> Let O be ToObject(base).

Which is effectively the same as `Object(str)`, which is effectively the same as `new String(str)`