# How to convert ISOString to local ISOString in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert ISOString to local ISOString in javascript?

I have [ISO 8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) style string(e.g. '2013-02-18T16:39:17+00:00')

And I want to convert that to local ISO_8601 style string...

```
'2013-02-18T16:39:17+00:00' -> '2013-02-19T01:39:17+09:00'
```

What should I do?

Comment: What happened to the s/milli/mikro seconds?

Comment: just I tried "new Date("2013-02-18T16:39:17+00:00").toLocaleString()"

Comment: But that is not ISO 8086 style...

Answer (score 1):

There only is a [`.toISOString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), but that will not use the local timezone. For that, you will need to format the string yourself:

```
function toLocaleISOString(date) {
    function pad(n) { return ("0"+n).substr(-2); }

    var day = [date.getFullYear(), pad(date.getMonth()+1), pad(date.getDate())].join("-"),
        time = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()].map(pad).join(":");
    if (date.getMilliseconds())
        time += "."+date.getMilliseconds();
    var o = date.getTimezoneOffset(),
        h = Math.floor(Math.abs(o)/60),
        m = Math.abs(o) % 60,
        o = o==0 ? "Z" : (o<0 ? "+" : "-") + pad(h) + ":" + pad(m);
    return day+"T"+time+o;
}
```

Comment: Thats the best `pad` implementation in JS I have seen so far :)

Comment: @migg: It's a quite [standard implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5366849/1048572).