# custom formating to variable imacros

Tags: variables, formatting, integer, format, imacros

Hey everyone basically I have a variable in imacros that I increment each time , it has an integer value.
I loop from `0` to `1000` , however what I want to be displayed is `0000` to `1000` , what is displayed is of course `0, 1, 2...1000.`
Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: no build-in way to do it. the only way is to modify values on-the-fly before use adding zeros at the begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution with JS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366849/convert-1-to-0001-in-javascript)

Example:

```
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
        {
         var str = "" + i;
         var pad = "0000";
         iimDisplay(pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str);
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, didnt know that javascripted integrated with imacros !