# Converting 1 to 0001 in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have an array in javascript. It specifies URLs for images 1-1050. My images must be named 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg ect... However my script is calling up 1.jpg, 2.jpg... 
I am very new to JS and am struggling to incorporate an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366849/convert-1-to-0001-in-javascript) with my script.

```
for (i = 0001; i < 1050; i++) {
 images.push('/images/' + i + '.jpg');
}
```

Comment: What problems to you have implementing that answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5366862/407650

Answer (score 9):

To combine what you linked and yours:

```
for (i = 1; i < 1050; i++) {
  var str = "" + i
  var pad = "0000"
  str = pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str
  images.push('/images/' + str + '.jpg');
}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted it at first and kept on having to edit it.  The version as it is now should work.  If it doesn't please tell me

Comment: Easiest to read for me. Although, had to add pad to images.push to work fully.

Comment: oops.  Still wasn't quite perfect.  I'm glad it worked, though.  Please accept it if you like it!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a utility function which convert a integer to a 4 digits string representation:

```
function intTo4digitsString(nb) {
   if(nb > 0 && nb < 10)
        return "000"+nb;
   else if(nb >= 10 && nb < 100)
        return "00"+nb;
   else if(nb >= 100 && nb < 1000)
        return "0"+nb;
}
```

This version is limited to 4 digits (and not as easily extensible than other answers), but I think it's more readable fr you :) Then you can use:

```
for (i = 1; i < 1050; i++) {
    images.push('/images/' + inTo4DigitsString(i) + '.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
for (i = 1; i < 1050; i++)
{
    var name = '0000' + i;
    images.push('/images/' + name.substr(name.length - 4) + '.jpg');
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4z5Sd/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mattsjo. Had to add 'pad' to array for it to work fully.

```
for (i = 1; i < 1050; i++) {
  var str = "" + i
  var pad = "0000"
  var padd = pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str
  images.push('/images/' + padd + '.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general purpose string formatting function then the [`sprintf`](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) library might work for you.

```
var i, images = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 1050; i++) {
    images.push(sprintf('/images/%04d.jpg', i));
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjzP/)

Comment: Having used this before, i'd suggest you profile it in jsperf.  It's not a great function to be using in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
zeropad = function( n,l ){ 
    var ret, d, i;
    ret = n === null || n === undefined ? '' : n.toString();
    // do we need to pad or truncate?
    d = l - ret.length;
    if (d>0) {
        for (i=0;i<d; i++) {
            ret = '0'+ret;
        }
    }
    return(ret);
};
images.push('/images/'+zeropad(i,4) + '.jpg');
```

From a library I wrote a while back. https://github.com/deitch/jsorm-utilities

Answer (score 0):

```
function padNum(num,length)
{
    return Array((length+1)-num.toString().length).join("0")+num;
}

padNum(1,4);//0001
padNum(250,4);//0250
```

And then in your code:

```
images.push('/images/' + padNum(i,4) + '.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
for (i = 1; i < 1050; i++) {        
    images.push('/images/' + ('0000'.substring(0, i.toString().length)+i) + '.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
for (var i = 1;i<1050;i++){
    images.push("/images/"+(Array(5-(""+i).length)).join("0")+i+".jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
Number.prototype.leftPad = function (len) {
    var l = this.toString().length,
        d = len - l;
    return new Array(d + 1).join('0') + this.toString();
};

for (var i = 1, len = 1051; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(i.leftPad(4) + '.jpg');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PxC5B/).

References:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).
- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).

Answer (score 0):

```
function pad(val, len) {
    return ("000000000000000000" + val).substr(len * -1);
}
```

Usage:

```
console.log(pad(1, 4) + ".jpg");
> 0001.jpg
```