# Simply transform my date format

Tags: javascript, time

I have:

```
(new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

I want it returns without UTC:

```
2013-08-31
```

I try:

```
new Date().getYear() + "-" + new Date().getMonth() + "-" + new Date().getDay()
```

But it does not work. It returns: 113-7-6.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Please** take the time to [read some documentation for the three `Date` methods you're using,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which should make it quite obvious why you're not getting the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

- `Date.getYear()` returns the year (usually 2-3 digits) in the specified date according to local time, and is deprecated. Use `Date.getFullYear()` instead.
- `Date.getMonth()` returns a zero-indexed value, so you need to add `1` to get `8`.
- `Date.getDay()` returns zero-indexed day of the week. Use `Date.getDate()` instead to get `31`.

You'll need to zero-pad `8` to get a string with `08` in it, by the way. Or you could simplify everything and [use a date formatting library](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) – you'll still need to read documentation, though.

Recommended reading:

- [MDN `Date` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/139010)
- [convert '1' to '0001' in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5366849/139010)