# Printing a formatted multiplication table to the console

Tags: javascript, console

my current code currently prints a table to the console, but I want the table to be formatted so every column and row are aligned perfectly. I can do that using an HTML table, but I would prefer just printing in the console.

```html
console.log(multiplicationTable(12));

function multiplicationTable(max)
{
    var i,j;
    for( i = 1; i<=max ; i++)
        {
            for( j = 1; j<=max; j++)
                {
                    document.write( i*j + " " );
                }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `currently prints a table to the console` no it doesn't - it logs `undefined` to the console

Answer (score 0):

How about using the "console.table(~~)" ?

Comment: console.table (at least in firefox) seems to be limited to 10 columns

Comment: exactly, plus I can't use console.table

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use another string contain spaces to join your string.

You can have a look at this: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5366862/4103909)

Short answer:

```
var str = ""; //your string
var pad = "0000"; //the buffer string
var ans = pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str //get the length of your buffer and minus your string to get the remaining '0'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formatted `table` inside your `console`:

```js
console.log(multiplicationTable(12));

function multiplicationTable(max) {
  var i, j;
  document.write("<table border='1'>");
  for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
      document.write("<td>" + i * j + "</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}
```