# Function that pads with zeros an input number

Tags: javascript, regex, padding

i'm having a serious issue here. I have a function that pads a user's input with zeros. For example if i enter 88 it will normalize it to:
00000088. My function is this:

```
export default length => (value) => {
  const noLeadingZeros = value.toString().replace(/(0+)/, '');
  if (noLeadingZeros.length === 0) {
    return value;
  }
  return padLeft(noLeadingZeros, length);
};
```

with padleft is:

```
export default (num, len) => (
  len > num.toString().length ? '0'.repeat(len - num.toString().length) + num
    : num
);
```

My problem is that if i entered something like this:
80112345 it convert it to 08112345. Any ideas?

Comment: wrong replacement ... what is it for?

Comment: Why do you need to remove leading zeroes, if you're just going to add them back in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert '1' to '0001' in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366849/convert-1-to-0001-in-javascript)

Comment: Anchor the regex: `/^(0+)/` As it is now, you're removing *all* the `0` characters from the string.

Comment: in your replacement, you are just deleting every zero from your number, even the zeros *inside* the number

Comment: In which instance would a number.tostring give you leading zeros?

Comment: Also the `.replace()` function will *never* return the number 0.

Comment: @Musa if value is already a string with leading zeros.

Comment: You could refactor `padleft` like this `'0'.repeat(len > String(num).length ? len - String(num).length : 0) + num;` to make it a little more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks wrong :

```
const noLeadingZeros = value.toString().replace(/(0+)/, '');
```

you are deleting every zeros out of your number... even those inside !

You can use this regex instead, instead of for `/(0+)/` in your code :

```
 /\b(0+)/
```

explanation : the `\b` ensures the zeros are at the beginning of a word

or this

```
 /^(0+)/
```

explanation : the `^` ensure this is the beginning of the string

Answer (score 2):

In your replace, you're replacing all the zeros in the number not just those on the left side, and even if there are zeros on the left side, why remove them if you're just going to add them back. You could use a for loop that pads the string with a zero `n` times (where `n` is the number of digits that the string needs to have length 8), or (thanks to a comment by @AndrewBone), you can use the `.repeat()` function that does this for you:

```js
function padLeft(value, len) {
  return '0'.repeat(String(value).length < len ? len - String(value).length : 0) + value;
}
console.log(padLeft("", 8));
console.log(padLeft("88", 8));
console.log(padLeft("00088", 8));
console.log(padLeft("12312388", 8));
console.log(padLeft("00000000", 8));
```

Comment: I thought their `.repeat()` was quite nice already something like this would be nice https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/y3hco12x/

Answer (score 2):

Using `slice`:

```js
let str = '00000000' + 88;
let resp = str.slice(-8, str.length)
console.log(resp) // 00000088
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a RegEx to assert that the number is a valid number.

```
/0+/
```

Then get the number of digits in the number:

```
('' + num).length;
```

Then put the whole thing together

```
var paddedNum ='';
for (var i=0;i<8-len;i++) {
  paddedNum += "0";
}
paddedNum += num;
```