# jquery string + add extra characters to start

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following JQUERY Function:

```
function siteCounterUpdate(n) {
    $('ul#indexSiteCounterBottom').empty();
    for(i=0;i<9;i++) {

            //alert(n.toString()[i]);

      $('ul#indexSiteCounterBottom').append('<li>'+n.toString()[i]+'</li>');
      $('ul#indexSiteCounterBottom li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('extra-margin');
    }
}
```

The function receives a number (string) and if its 9 characters long it works perfectly. 9 is the full length.

However if the number is say 7 characters long I need the first 2 items to be replaced with a HTML no breaking space.

```
&nbsp;
```

I'm struggling to understand how I can do this.

eg: 
6 character long string would be
1. nbsp
2. nbsp
3. nbsp
4 - 9. the string.

any advice would be great.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to pad a string:

```
function padString (str, len, padWith) {
    var padLength = len - str.length;
    return padLength < 1 ? str : Array(padLength + 1).join(padWith) + str;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
padString('1234567899', 9, '&nbsp;'); // "1234567899"
padString('123456789', 9, '&nbsp;');  // "123456789"
padString('12345678', 9, '&nbsp;');   // "&nbsp;12345678"
padString('1234567', 9, '&nbsp;');    // "&nbsp;&nbsp;1234567"
padString('234567', 9, '&nbsp;');     // "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;234567"
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8JdwP/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of `for` loops like so to count between `n` and `9` for your `&nbsp;`'s and `0` and `n` for your string:

```
function siteCounterUpdate(n) {
    var target = $('ul#indexSiteCounterBottom').empty();

    for (var i=n.length;i<9;i++) {
        target.append('<li>&nbsp;</li>');
    }

    // `i` doesn't have to be declared again because there's no block
    // scope in JavaScript, but I think it looks ugly otherwise :(.
    for (var i=0;i<n.length;i++) {
        target.append('<li>' + n + '</li>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be confused about what you want, but could you just right-align the counter so you don't need the spaces?

If not, you could create a pad function like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466135/adding-extra-zeros-in-front-of-a-number-using-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

```
while (yourString.length < 9)
{
    yourString = "\u00A0" + yourString;   
}
```

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/u7BYz/)