# Padding zero to the left of number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a ten digit number that will always be constant. I want to pad it so, that it will always remove a zero for every extra number added to the number. Can someone please show me an example of how I can do this?

eg. 0000000001

```
0000000123 
0000011299
```

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841773/javascript-format-number-to-day-with-always-3-digits?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868353/how-to-zero-pad-numbers-in-javascript?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828797/form-field-input-number-automatically-convert-to-3-digit-by-adding-zeros-in-fro?lq=1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

**Output**

```
pad("123", 10);    // => "0000000123"
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/trip007/KSJZq/25/)**

Comment: Simply use native padding 
"123".padStart(10, '0'); // => "0000000123"

Answer (score 9):

Just try with:

```
function zeroPad(input, length) {
    return (Array(length + 1).join('0') + input).slice(-length);
}

var output = zeroPad(123, 10);
```

Output:

```
"0000000123"
```

Answer (score -2):

Another variant would be:

```
function pad(input, length) {
    return Array(length - Math.floor(Math.log10(input))).join('0') + input;
}

var out = pad(23, 4); // is "0023"
```