# How to add eight 0 before primary key using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create two separate functions in php and in javascript when I fetch my primary key and I pass it to my php function it adds eight time `0` when value of primary key came up to 10 then `0` numbers should be seven and when it came to `100` then `0` should be six before my primary key of mysql and same separate function in javascript.

When I pass it my primary key the same functionality should work in also javascript I try to find at google but there is not any example for it.

I know there is an option in mysql called zero filling but I want to do that with php and javascript.

Comment: php manual is your friend: [str_pad](http://php.net/str_pad)

Comment: thanks it worked in php but in javascript is there any function like `str_pad`?

Comment: what i recommend is once you converted your $id to 8 digit number instead of converting your id again in javascript pass already converted php $id value to javascript.

Answer (score 3):

in php you have two ways

```
1)sprintf('%08d', $id); 
and 
2)str_pad($id, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: str_pad worked for me Melon tell me about this function thanks but how to do this in javascript?

Comment: if you have a value already converted using php then pass that value only to javascript or vice versa. you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6466243/4599982 to javascript string formatting.