# remove zero before primary key

Tags: javascript, php

Hi few times ago I post question [how to add eight 0 before primary key using php and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874795/how-to-add-eight-0-before-primary-key-using-php-and-javascript) and I got my answers for both php and javascript and I create two functions for it.

PHP function

```
function addingZerosBeforeIds($ids){
     return str_pad($ids, 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

and javascript function

```
function addingZerosBeforeIds(input, length, string) {
     string = string || '0'; input = input + '';
     return input.length >= length ? input : new Array(length - input.length + 1).join(string) + input;
}
```

its working fine but now I want to remove zeros before primary key I tries a lot for this but didn't succeed how to do this.

Comment: To remove the leading zero, just convert the string to a number `str = +str;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in js you can simply do it like

```
parseInt("000123", 10); //123
```

and in php

```
intval("000123"); //123
```

Comment: doing parseInt("000123") without passing the radix will sometimes cause it to parse it as an octet. You must always pass in the radix. so parseInt("000123", 10) will insure that it gets parsed as base10 number, see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function removeZerosBeforeIds($input) {
        return preg_replace('/^0*/','',$input);
    }
```

Comment: I need two php and javascript functions

Answer (score 0):

you could simply just parse the Int.

javascript

```
str = parseInt(str, 10);
```

php

```
str = (int)$str;
```

Comment: I need two php and javascript functions.