# how to append double digit if user passed single digit value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on jquery.

i want to check the validation on todate and from date.

> want to convert my string into double digit (need to add 0 if user enter single digit value)

how can i give double digit as user enter single digit value into textbox?

```
expected output is 
  var HourPerWeek = $("#Hour").val(); 
 -- if user enter value 2 i need to convert it into 02
  var MinPerWeek = $("#Min").val();    
-- if user enter value 1 i need to convert it into 01
```

> Instead of length of string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work,just check the string length and then add a zero if it is shorter than 2

```
var HourPerWeek;
if ($("#Hour").val().length < 2){
   HourPerWeek = "0"+ $("#Hour").val(); 
}
else{
   HourPerWeek = $("#Hour").val();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function returnDoubleDigits(str) {
  return str.length === 1 ? '0' + str : str;
}
```

e.g.

```
var HourPerWeek = returnDoubleDigits($("#Hour").val());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tFsEc/)

Comment: It does not work if a actual number is passed. `("" + str).length` will do the trick.

Comment: A number was never going to be passed in. That's why I called my param `str`.

Comment: it is safe to make that method more generic.

Comment: Maybe so, but for the purposes of answering the question, my answer was valid.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the 0 to the beginning of the string manually like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14760377/1798215):

```js
String.prototype.paddingLeft = function (paddingValue) {
    return String(paddingValue + this).slice(-paddingValue.length);
};

var HourPerWeek = $("#Hour").val().paddingLeft('00');
```

Explanation: You can call paddingLeft on any string. It will add the chars, that you pass as an argument to the left of the string and return a string with exactly the length of the given argument. More examples:

```js
   ''.paddingLeft('00') // returns '00'
  '1'.paddingLeft('00') // returns '01'
 '11'.paddingLeft('00') // returns '11'
'111'.paddingLeft('00') // returns '11'
  '1'.paddingLeft('  ') // returns ' 1'
```

Comment: But i want to add `0` when there is a single digit entered

Answer (score -2):

Have this as a function which checks for length of passed parameter.

```
function returnTwoDigit(var Data){
if (Data.length != 2) {
    if (Data.length == 1) {
        Data= "0" + Data;
    }
    return Data
}
```

Comment: What if Data is number?

Comment: @Exception: I think it will still count number of digits in variable ````Data````, havn't tried it but thinks so.

Comment: If you try `.length` on number it will throw illegal exception. Make it `"" + Data` and the do the length operation for string and number.