# create a phone number from a seed number

Tags: javascript

I've been toying with a phone number creator function. It looks something like

```
createPhoneNumber(1) -- would return (000)000-0001
createPhoneNumber(5901) -- would return (000)000-5901
createPhoneNumber(18883141) -- would return (001)888-3141

function createPhoneNumber(number) {

//return properly formatted phone number

}
```

I can't figure out the logic to pad the numbers that have less than 10 digits.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems a simple matter of counting the number of characters you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript function that can pad a string to get to a determined length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
function phone(num, format) {
  var i = format.match(/0/g).length;
  num = [].slice.call(num).reverse();
  return format.replace(/0/g, function() { 
    return num[--i] || 0;
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
phone('12345', '(000)000-0000'); //=> (000)001-2345
phone('123456', '00-000-000'); //=> 00-123-456
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createPhoneNumber(number) {
    var digitsGiven = number & number.length ? number.length : 0;
    var digitZeros = 10-digitsGiven;
    var phoneNumber = '(';
    for (var i = 0; i < digitZeros.length; i++) {
        phoneNumber += '0';
    }
    phoneNumber += number;
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substr(0, 4) + ')' + phoneNumber.substr(4);
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substr(0, 8) + '-' + phoneNumber.substr(8);
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: In line 5, shouldn't it be i++ instead of i--

Answer (score 0):

you want [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
pn(1);
pn(5901);
pn(18883141);

function pn($num)
{
    $pad    = str_pad($num, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return '('.substr($pad, 0, 3).')'.substr($pad, 3, 3).'-'.substr($pad, 6, 4);
}
```