# Way to add leading zeroes to binary string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary

I've used .toString(2) to convert an integer to a binary, but it returns a binary only as long as it needs to be (i.e. first bit is a 1).

So where:

```
num = 2;
num.toString(2) // yields 10.
```

How do I yield the octet 00000010?

Comment: You could just add zeroes on the front of the result until it is the correct length.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337260/javascript-a-byte-is-suppose-to-be-8-bits

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
var n = num.toString(2);
n = "00000000".substr(n.length) + n;
```

Comment: Now you can use standard 'n.padStart(paddingSize, '0');'

Comment: @DevMultiTech, you should make yours an answer and it should be the chosen one. function pad(v,s=8){return v.toString(2).padStart(s, '0'); 1. pad(1); /* '00000001' */ 2. pad(1,2); /* '01' */

Answer (score 6):

You could just use a while loop to add zeroes on the front of the result until it is the correct length.

```
var num = 2,
    binaryStr = num.toString(2);

while(binaryStr.length < 8) {
    binaryStr = "0" + binaryStr;
}
```

Comment: Intuitive solution - thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this ...

```
function pad(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}
```

... then use it as ...

```
pad(num.toString(2), 8);
```