# Converting milliseconds while detecting single digit integers

Tags: javascript, function, time, integer

I created a function that detects and converts milliseconds to minutes and seconds. What I'd like to do is prepend a zero on either (or both) the minute and second variables if the number comes out to be less than ten. So for instance if I had an integer `184213` which evaluates to `3:4` I'd like it to be `03:04`. Is there a short and concise way to do this without having to write out a long conditional or ternary?

```js
msToTime(184213);

function msToTime(milliseconds) {
  var minutes = parseInt(milliseconds/(1000*60)%60),
      seconds = parseInt((milliseconds/1000)%60);
  return minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript function that can pad a string to get to a determined length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach utilizing [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
function msToTime(milliseconds) {
  var date = new Date(milliseconds);
  return date.toTimeString().slice(3,8);
}

msToTime(184213);
// outputs: "03:04"
```

A small caveat is this will of course have a limit of "23:59" and will always be the floor value as any milliseconds value over the minutes will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
msToTime(184213);

function msToTime(milliseconds) {
  var minutes = parseInt(milliseconds/(1000*60)%60),
      seconds = parseInt((milliseconds/1000)%60);
  return ('0' + minutes).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);
}
```