# limit the query exactly with 8 and 7 digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prefix

i have a little question:
how i can limit or generate the result of a query in 7 or 8 digits

example:

```
var x = 3143284294
var y = 387520525892
var z = -7632489234892
var w = 34563
```

result:

```
var x = 3143284
var y = 3875205
var z = -763248
var w = 3456300 (fill whit "0")
```

What function or prefix in javascript will use?

tnks(and sorry for my english)

Comment: Should it be 7 or 8? Randomly chosen? Your example only uses 7 digits (or 6 + the minus).

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-lengt

Comment: ramdomly, but the result always be 7 digits or 8

Comment: When should the result be seven digits an when should it be eight?

Comment: sorry seven or eight is random, but the result must be the same number of digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This converts the number to a string and performs string operations on it. Note that `repeat` is a fairly recent feature of ECMAScript.

```
function cutNum(n, limit) {
    n = n + '';
    n = n.substr(0, limit);
    if (n.length < limit) {
        n = n + '0'.repeat(limit - n.length);
    }
    return parseInt(n, 10);
}

var x = 3143284294;
cutNum(x, 7); // 3143284

var z = -7632489234892;
cutNum(z, 7); // -763248

var w = 34563;
cutNum(w, 7); // 3456300
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  the [slice() method.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)

```
 var numbers = "01234567890";
 var res = numbers.slice(0,6);
 alert(res);
```

Since your sample also includes that are less than 7 digits, you will want to run a logic check first prior to the slice.

```
var x = "01" 

if(x.length < 7)
  x = x + "0000000";
x = x.slice(0,6);
alert(x);
```

Comment: is random the 7 digits is an example i don't know how much digits appear, but tnks is result