# Preserve leading 0 when number is one digit

Tags: javascript, function

I am working with parseInt() function in JavaScript and need to apply logic as if given number is less than 10 then add 0 before number.

So, if given number is 9 then print it as 09. What i apply is:

```
if (no < 10) {
    no = "0" + no;
}
```

and the apply parseInt() method on it but every time leading zero is flash-out.

Comment: If it's already a number why do you need to involve `parseInt()` at all?

Comment: thats what parse int will do. why do you need pars int **after** you have prefixed the value?

Comment: no is converted to string, when assigning string.

Comment: Maybe this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng) helps :)

Comment: You must do the reverse, parseInt() and then do the padding

Comment: parseInt() was there when i got code to apply, So i cannot remove it, so need to add logic or patch to figure out this.

Comment: @Kiran: if you want to **redefine** parseInt() -- as your last comment suggests -- please edit your question accordingly (even if it sounds like a rather bad idea).

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, an [integer (Number)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) cannot have a leading zero. If you want a leading zero, you should present it as a string.

```
parseInt('01', 10); // 1
parseFloat('01'); // 1
parseInt(01, 10); // 1
```

A useful function for adding padding to a number converted to a string. Feel free to put this in your own utils or other helper-toolbelt. Happy padding!

```
 /**
 * Add padding (leading zero's) to integer, based on minimum length
 * @param {Number} integer 
 * @param {Number} minimal length of returned string
 * @return {String} padded string
 */
function addPadding(integer, length){
  var integerString = integer + '';
    while (integerString.length < length) {
      integerString = '0' + integerString;
    }
  return integerString;
}

// Output examples
addPadding(15, 3);  // 015
addPadding(4, 2);   // 04
addPadding(123, 2); // 123
addPadding(123, 5); // 00123
```

Comment: You should always use a radix with `parseInt`.

Comment: Yeah, I know...Quick and dirty answering. Now added the parameter :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert it to a string since numbers don't make sense with leading zeros.

So you must print the number as:

```
if (no < 10) {
    console.log("0" + no);
}
```

If `no = 8`, then result is `"08"`

Answer (score 0):

First, **always** use a base of `10` with `parseInt()`.

Second, use `console.log()` to see what you get:

```
no = parseInt(user_input, 10); // base 10
console.log(typeof no);
if (no < 10) {
    no = "0" + no;
}
console.log(typeof no);
```

This should give you in the console output:

```
number
string
```

> A leading `0` in the **input** may get in the way as it is an octal representation and `8` or `9` are not a valid numerals. The **output** cannot have a leading `0` as a `number` and as such, must be kept as a `string`.

The last point is not a problem if you correctly separate the actual number from the numeral in your code:

```
no_to_compute = 8;         // is a number type
no_to_display = "0" + no;  // ia a string type:
                           // representation of the number (numeral)
```