# Maintaining string length by adding zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass a string with at least has a length of 10. How do I add 0's to fill the remaining blank spaces so it will always have a length of 10?

This is what I tried but does not work as expected.

```
var passString = "Abcdefg";
if (passString.length<10){
      var len = passString.length;
      var missing = 10-len;
      passString = passString + Array(missing).join("0")
}
```

Comment: to the left or to the right?

Comment: try `(passString + Array(11).join('0')).substr(0,10)` ... no wait, that will limit to 10 regardless)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. 0's at the end.

Comment: ignore my suggestion - it limits to 10 regardless

Comment: @JaromandaX `it limits to 10 regardless` Not if checking for `passString.length<10`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-lengt Same basic idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat zeros to the end of the string and use slice or substring or substr.

```
var passString = "ABC";
var fixed = (passString + "0000000000").slice(0,10);
console.log(fixed);
```

Based on comment, I skipped the if, but you can just do a basic if

```
var passString = "ABC";
var fixed = passString;
if (passString.length<10) {
    fixed = (passString + "0000000000").slice(0,10);
}
console.log(fixed);
```

or  ternary operator

```
var passString = "ABC";
var fixed = passString >=10? passString : (passString + "0000000000").slice(0,10);
console.log(fixed);
```

or just override the original with an if

```
var passString = "ABC";
if (passString.length<10) {
    passString = (passString + "0000000000").slice(0,10);
}
console.log(passString);
```

Comment: My fav...Thank you! You're awesome!

Comment: The only issue is that it cuts of from 10. I need to maintain a minimum length of 10. Hope this makes scene. :)

Comment: Cool! that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

please try below code

```
var passString = "Abcdefg";
if (passString.length<10){
      var len = passString.length;
      var missing = 10-len;
      passString =passString+  new Array(missing + 1).join("0");
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line (I love giving one liners)

```
passString = (passString + Array(11).join('0')).substr(0,Math.max(10,passString.length))
```