# Convert string to hex then back to string

Tags: javascript

I have to convert a working C# function to JavaScript so it executes client-side.  Here's the C#...

```
// convert the cmac into a hex number so we can increment it and get the emac
long emacLong = Convert.ToInt64(_cmac, 16) + 1;
emac = emacLong.ToString("x12").ToUpper();
```

Here's what I have so far in JavaScript..

```
var emac = parseInt(cmac, 16) + 1;
emac = emac.toString(16);
```

The input is "0015D1833339".  The output should be "0015D183333A".  However, the JavaScript returns "15d183333a".  I need to retain the leading 0's.  Looks like the C# function accomplishes this with the "x12" parameter of .ToString.  How do I accomplish this in JavaScript?  I need to convert it to an integer, increment it by 1 and then convert back to a string with a length of 12 characters.

Comment: You'd have to pad with zeros until the length is 12

Comment: You just need to pad the resulting string.  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14760377

Comment: *Convert to uppercase* and pad with zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way to pad hex number output when you know the exact length you desire is with something like this:

```
var emac = parseInt(cmac, 16) + 1;
emac = ("000000000000" + emac.toString(16)).substr(-12);

// or if you MUST have all caps....
emac = ("000000000000" + emac.toString(16)).substr(-12).toUpperCase();
```

This example is for length 12, if you need a different length, you would adjust the length of the 0 string and the substr param.

Comment: You only need eleven `0`s, and you forgot the `.toUpperCase()` ;)

Comment: I didn't add toUpperCase because OP didn't specifically ask for it. But your right about only needing eleven. Kept it consistent with the substr length for simplicity.

Comment: OP stated: *The output should be "0015D183333A"*. Come on, I'm waiting to give you a +1 for posting the answer just before I was going to :)

Comment: Perfecto!  Works like a charm!  I can handle the .toUpperCase(), but thanks for pointing out my omission.  ;)