# Use FOR loop to add additional characters or symbols each loop iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Using a `FOR` loop to add and output numbers is easy.  But how do you add and output additional characters?

For example the following simple program outputs the numbers 1 through 7 to the `console`.

```
for (var count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
    console.log(count + 1);
}
```

But what if instead of numbers I needed to add additional characters or symbols each loop?  For example how would someone output characters to the `console` like this?

A

AA

AAA

AAAA

AAAAA

AAAAAA

AAAAAAA

I'm sure the answer is straightforward but I don't know how to approach this type of problem.

Comment: Have another for loop inside that loops from 1 to count, and output a character at each iteration.  After the inner for loop emit the line break

Comment: `var txt = ""; for(var count = 0; count < 7; count++) { console.log(txt+="A"); }`

Comment: Also, see these questions and answers about writing a pad function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng

Comment: @mjw you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple loop for text appending:

```
var txt = ""; 
for(var count = 0; count < 7; count++) { 
    console.log(txt+="A"); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is rather easy.

```
for (var count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
    switch (count) {
        case 7: console.log('AAAAAAA'); break;
        case 6: console.log('AAAAAA'); break;
        case 5: console.log('AAAAA'); break;
        case 4: console.log('AAAA'); break;
        case 3: console.log('AAA'); break;
        case 2: console.log('AA'); break;
        case 1: console.log('A'); break;
        case 0: console.log('xd'); break;
    }
}
```

Okay... jokes aside.

But for real:

```
for (var count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
    console.log(new Array(count + 1).join('A'));
}
```

Or if you badly want to append:

```
for (var str = ""; str.length < 10; str += "A") {
    console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: That would work, but rather unwieldy and doesn't scale well. e.g. if you had to do that 1000s of times

Comment: I gave better answer :)

Comment: Danny, you code only works for count = 1 through 7.  What if I want 8 or more? ;-P

Comment: @vbguyny copypaste more!!

Comment: people have no shame

Comment: It is called joke, I gave the most scalable answer :)

Comment: have some pts friend

Comment: [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: @PetterFriberg why? When I hit 12k rep I will hate fun too?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I will remember your name, and I will write when I pass that some day.