# Alternative way to padStart

Tags: javascript

I have an Integer input that I want to output as 2 digits.

**Besides using `padStart()`**

```
String(month).padStart(2, '0')
```

My current solution:

```
`${String(month).length > 1 ? '' : '0'}${month}`
```

Is there a more elegant/another way to do the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng

Comment: What's wrong with `padStart`?

Comment: I'd rather check whether the number is less than 10 than to check whether the String-number's `length` is greater than 1

Comment: @CertainPerformance congrats on the gold [tag:javascript] badge! Well deserved

Comment: @Phil I'm using a node that's not supporting `padStart()` yet; so thought of writing one myself instead of using polyfill

Comment: great idea @CertainPerformance!

Comment: `('0'+month).substr(-2)`

Comment: or add the polyfill from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Polyfill ... then start using modern javascript :p