# how can i make all the filenames the same length by adding spaces to it?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, character, filenames, batch-rename

i want to make the filename+spaces=211 characters
but the problem is that if the file name characters = 30

i would need  181 spaces

while if file name characters = 80

i would need  131 spaces

i have tried advanced renamer

tags options + spaces .

```
<Name>
```

.. 
and even this script in the scripts section

```
var maxLength = 25;
var name = item.name;
var date = app.parseTags("<Year Modified><Month Modified><Day Modified>");
var numSpaces = maxLength - name.length - date.length;
var spaces = "";
for (i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) spaces += " ";
return name + spaces + date;
```

but it give me this error 
[name is not defined in the line 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1mtC.png)

Comment: What is the value of numSpaces in your example above before you use the for loop? Also looks like you have a typo, (var i = 0;) ==> you are missing the var in your forloop.

Comment: If you fix that typo your code will word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript function that can pad a string to get to a determined length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script that works using advanced Renamer

```
var maxLength = 222;
var name = item.name;
var date = app.parseTags("<Year Modified><Month Modified><Day Modified>");
var numSpaces = maxLength - name.length - date.length;
var spaces = "";
for (i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) spaces += " ";
return name + spaces + date;
```

credits  [David Lee from advanced Renamer forms](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/users_show?user_id=2502)

Comment: please note that  "if you set the filename +extension to 227 characters then the rest of your file path including volume name must be shorter than 33 characters otherwise Windows will throw an error when you run the batch. "

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#padEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd), to add whitespaces to the end of your filename strings so that the resulting string has a minimum length a specified by you.

Consider the snippet below until where `fileNameA.padEnd(211)` returns a new string with the same leading characters as `fileNameA`, but with whitespaces padding the remainder of the string such that the string has length `211`:

```js
const fileNameA = 'your file name';
const fileNameB = 'some other big file name';

const paddedFileNameA = fileNameA.padEnd(211);
const paddedFileNameB = fileNameB.padEnd(211);

console.log(`
paddedFileNameA:
"${paddedFileNameA}"
length of paddedFileNameA: ${paddedFileNameA.length}
`)
console.log(`
paddedFileNameB:
"${paddedFileNameB}"
length of paddedFileNameB: ${paddedFileNameB.length}
`)
```

#### Update

I'm not familiar with the scripting feature set in Advanced Renamer, however you might find this works for you:

```
/*
Set length to 211
*/
var maxLength = 211; 
var name = item ? item.name : '';
var date = app.parseTags("<Year Modified><Month Modified><Day Modified>");

/*
Ensure variables are not undefined or null
*/
if(!name) {
    name = '';
}
if(!date) {
    date = '';
}

/*
Construct result string
*/
var result = name;
for (i = 0; i < (maxLength - (name.length + date.length)); i++) {
    result += ' ';
}
result += date;

return result;
```

Comment: your script is great but it doesn't work on advanced renamer .... 
the reason that i use it that there's item.name and batch rename so i don't have to type the name for every single file ! https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/method_script
what do you suggest ?

Comment: @minanageh thanks - just updated answer. Does that help you?

Comment: i don't what the is problem !! it keeps saying invalid  script

Comment: what happens if you remove the very last `}` character in the updated code?

Comment: @minanageh sorry, just noticed the `item` and `index` were out of order. I just revised the code in the updated part of the answer.

Comment: thanks ... someone give the script that works in another forms

Comment: "just noticed the item and index were out of order" it works but it doesn't do anything ....