# How to loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

DISCLAIMER: i'm legit a newbie

I have a 2nd parameter in the getInput function, I should use it for the 9 zeros that I should input. But I don't know how to loop it to become 9 zeros instead of putting it in a variable.

How do I loop and store 9 zero's into my "digit" parameter without declaring it as `var zr = "000000000"`

here's my code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Search</title> 
  <script>
    //This method does the processing

     function getInput(input, digit){
      var str=input.substring(0,input.length);
      var padd0=9-str.length;


      var zr="000000000";
      var zrsub=zr.substring(0,padd0);
      var output="A"+zrsub+""+str;

      //can also be var output=input[0]+zrsub+""+str;

     return output;
    }


    //Displays output
    function showOutput(){
       var input=document.getElementById("search-input").value;
       var dislay=document.getElementById("search-output");
       dislay.value=getInput(input);
    }

  </script>

</head> 

<body> 
  <div class="wrapper"> 

    <input type="text" id="search-input">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="ENTER" onclick="showOutput()"> <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="search-output"> 

  </div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Sorry just a newbie in this whole programming thing. Just a little confused.

Comment: What is the expected output you want ?

Comment: when i input 1234, it will output A000001234. fixed to 9 numbers only
or if I input 202 it will ouput A000000202

Comment: @randombee check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng

Comment: What&#39;s the problem with your approach? If the max length is 9 then it&#39;s ok to have zr of length 9 and take substring as per the input length. You can declare zr outside the function and use it as a const

Comment: @gp. uh yeah my instructor wants me to add a parameter that serves as a storage of zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### with for loop join string

```
function joinString(input,digit) {
  
  var inputArr = input.split("");
  // var n = 9; // the length of the ouput string;
  for (var i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
    inputArr.unshift(0);
    if (inputArr.length === digit) {
      return inputArr.join("");
    }
  }
}
console.log(joinString("123456"));
```

Comment: yes i tried that but I don't want to put 9 zeros because there may be 8 numbers or 6 that's why i chose to loop it. but i dont know how

Comment: that's not a problem you can pass in the input 1to9 any number based on the length of the input it add zero like you have a input "5331234" so the output is "005331234"

Comment: this worked thanks!! but how do I add "digit" as a new parameter so it would become the value of n = 9???

Comment: oh nevermind i got it, it's supposed to be `console.log(joinString("123456",9));` am i right? thank you for your help! i appreciate it so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use padStart

```js
function getInput(input, digit){
    return 'A'+ input.toString().padStart(digit, '0');
}

document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = getInput(132,9)
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
```

IE may not support it though.

Comment: yeah i tried it but didn't work. i just really need to store it in the parameter and loop it pls help me

Comment: Sorry.. didn't get the problem. it should work according the the documentations here..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Tell me what you are trying to achieve? Is the goal is to leverage that 2nd parameter?

Comment: The digit parameter should contain the value of zeros and loop it like 0<9 or something because i dont want to store it in a simple variable. i just dont know how to loop it's my first time

Comment: I have edited.. try this. Assuming both the parameters will be numbers. And the digit parameter defines the total length of the string without the 'A' in the beginning .

Comment: tried to input 123 for example. but the output is only A123 so it didn't work.

Comment: I have added a snippet. run it

Comment: is it like this? please check https://codepen.io/randombee/pen/KKKKYjg

Comment: Where's your input for the 2nd parameter? and you have sent only one parameter to that function.