# Jquery function for padding characters to the end of a string

Tags: javascript, string, function, string-concatenation

Is there a built in function to pad characters `n` number of times?

Ex:

```
var myString = 'something';
var myCharToPad = '-';
var numTimesToPad = 5;
```

I am expecting `myString = 'something-----';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeat String - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript)

Comment: Paddnig is usually at the front of the string, do you need the option of which end to pad?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, but it's not hard:

```
myString += new Array(numTimesToPad+1).join(myCharToPad);
```

Comment: Why the `numTimesToPad+1` while declaring the `Array`?

Comment: @Tim Down - not true.  It makes assigning large arrays much, much quicker.  @Dusty - because `new Array(1).join('-')` gives `""`

Comment: @Tim Down - Yes.  :/  You just helped me find a ___very___ interesting bug (at least to me): http://jsperf.com/newarrayassign/2 (view in chrome)

Comment: @cwolves: It's an odd set of results in all versions of Chrome listed there. There must some internal Chrome heuristics going on.

Comment: @Tim Down - Chrome allocates memory for the entire array if there are < 100,000 elements.  Once it hits 100,000 it stops (makes sense, in case someone does `new Array(1,000,000,000)`.  So it's faster to pre-define the array up-to 100,000 elements :) (in chrome).  Other browsers vary, but there are benchmarks that it is almost always a good thing.

Comment: @cwolves: Yes, that was my assumption too. What I found odd was that my random choice of large number for the test happened to be the cut-off point for Chrome's heuristics.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, but it's trivial to write one:

```
function pad(num, string, char) {
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        string += char;
    }
    return string;
}

var myString = pad(5, 'something', '-')
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a repeated entry; you should **always** check first and if nobody has an answer, which is almost impossible [sorry but chances are that you are not that special] then post... that even saves you time by solving your issue faster.
You can find my "almost" ultimate answer to the JS padding issue at [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript/13063358#13063358) also on this site.