# Getting the masked value of a password field?

Tags: jquery, html, input, passwords

I've got a normal password field from which I would like to "get" the masked value - yep, that ugly `**********` obfuscated value.

HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"></input>
```

JS/JQ DOM:

```
$("#password").val(); // Password in cleartext
```

Comment: The masked value is just a series of the same characters. It's useless.

Comment: Really though, why would you need the "masked value"? You just want the number of characters right? Some browsers show asterisks, some show big dots, etc.

Comment: What do you mean the masked value?The masked value is simply the clear text but obfuscated so that other people can't see it.The password of course is sent as is (the value IS what you enter, if you write 'password' in a password field, the value of that field IS password) otherwise how would the server check if your username/password combo is correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean that you want a string that contains as much `*` as the number of characters you inserted in a password field you could do:

```
var password = $("#password").val();
password  = password.replace(/./g, '*');
```

Comment: Maybe i'm stupid but i understood that he was implying that the there is a 'masked' value of the password. Seeing other answers i'm wrong, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: It's not an answer. It's a comment. I'm not saying that what you wrote in it is wrong.

Comment: That's a clean oneliner. Thank you!

Comment: @Zootious i didn't copy your answer, i just edited a previous one i did (we mad the post more or less at the same time and we thought the same thing! :))

Answer (score 3):

Get [a string repeat function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript) on the go, then use this:

```
repeat('*', $('#myfield').val().length);
```

or (depending on the implementation you go with):

```
'*'.repeat($('#myfield').val().length);
```

---

My personal suggestion:

```
function repeat(s, n) {
    return new Array(isNaN(n) ? 1 : ++n).join(s);
}

var password = "lolcakes";
console.log(repeat('*', password.length));
// ^ Output: ********
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/SUcg3/)

Answer (score 1):

Do a regex replace on `$("#myfield").val();` that replaces all characters with `*` ?

```
alert($("#myfield").val().replace(/./g, '*'));
```

Comment: I doubt this will affect performance to any discernible degree.

Comment: That's not *your* point maybe, if your goal is to save a few cpu cycles. *My* point is to do a simple task in one easily read line, without having to create a helper function.

Comment: This approach promotes poor coding practices. You can solve this problem in a single line without a helper function (although a helper function is the _right_ thing to create here) without resorting to spooling up an entire pattern matching engine.