# How do I generate 'h' x n in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeat String - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript)

```
'h' x n;
```

Here `n` is a variable, and the generated string should be `n` times duplicate of `h`:

```
hh..h( n occurance of h in all)
```

Comment: Check out this answer:

[Repeat String - Javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript

Answer (score 10):

Here's a cute way to do it with no looping:

```
var n = 20;
var result = Array(n+1).join('h');
```

It creates an empty array of a certain length and then joins all the empty elements of the array putting your desired character between the empty elements - thus ending up with a string of all the same character n long.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PCweL/

Comment: It's probably faster, too, as it avoids the intermediate strings.

Comment: Would that be `Array(n+1)`?  You'd need `n-1` delimiters to join `n` things, leaving you one short...  (Change the 20 to 3 to see the issue more clearly.)

Comment: @cHao - you are right - I corrected it.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(n){
  var n = n || 0, s = '', i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    s += this;
  }
  return s;
}

"h".repeat(5) // output: "hhhhh"
```

Something like that perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question following may be the solution.

```
var n = 10;
var retStr = "";
for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) {
retStr += "h";
}

return retStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
function repeat(h, n) {
    var result = h;
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
       result += h;
    return result;
}
```