# jQuery - multiplying alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any simple way to multiply alphanumeric string in jQuery / JS?

e.g

```
var str = "ABC";
console.log( str * 5 ); // this will nerutn `Nan`
// where what i want is `ABCABCABCABCABC`
```

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say _definite_ duplicate. There are some good answers in the older thread.

Comment: @Dade, use the close link in the post to link to duplicates.

Comment: @epascarello It isn't showing a close link.

Comment: @Dade, you need more rep I guess! :)

Comment: @epascarello Odd, I see the delete link on all of the other pages though......

Comment: @Dade, The [rep limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) to close is 3000. Some reason I thought it was 1K. Get more rep! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see the exact question here:

[Repeat String - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript)

Just add this to your code:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function( num )
{
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}

var str = "ABC";
console.log( str.repeat(5) ); // this will return `ABCABCABCABCABC`
```

Comment: this looks way cleaner, and makes for creative use of `Array.join`. :D +1!

Comment: Thread should be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

Try extending the `String` object with a prototype function.

```
String.prototype.repeat = function (n) {
    var str = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) { str += this; }
    return str;
};
```

so that you can do it like this:

```
console.log(str.repeat(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.duplicate = function( numTimes ){
  var str = "";
  for(var i=0;i<numTimes;i++){
      str += this;
  }
  return str;
};

console.log( "abc".duplicate(2) );
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/upuqew/)

Answer (score 0):

This returns Nan because str is not a number.

You should do like this :

```
var str = "ABC";
console.log( multiply(str,num) );
```

With the function

```
function multiply(str,num){
        for ( var int = 0; int < length; int++) {
         str += str;
        }
        return str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.multi = function(num) {
 var n=0,ret = "";
 while(n++<num) {
  ret += this;
 }
 return ret;
};
```

And then use .multi(5) on any string you want :) Like:

```
var s = "ABC";
alert( s.multi(5) );
```