# 'x' * 5 is 'xxxxx' in Python – How do I do that in CoffeeScript/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, coffeescript

I want to create a string by concatenating multiple copies of another in CoffeeScript or JavaScript.

Do I have to create my own function for this or is there a shortcut like in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this shortcut (need to pass the number of repetitions plus 1):

```
Array(6).join 'x'
```

Comment: This is similar to the accepted answer to [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript).

Comment: @JustinNiessner: I edited for a reason. It won't work in this form in plain Javascript.

Comment: That only gets you four x's. Fence post problem.

Comment: @jAndy - It will work properly in CoffeeScript (it's not JavaScript).

Comment: Not sure about coffe script, but in javascript (chromes console) I got; `new Array(5).join('x') == 'xxxx'` (4 'x' only)

Comment: @JustinNiessner: You should at least add the line as valid js-function call since the OP also asked for javascript.

Comment: @jAndy - The OP asked for a CoffeeScript solution. I provided one.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: well, if you ignore the parenthesis, you're right.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: naarh, ok I should have been more explicit on that comment. What I meant was, the parenthesis in the OP's question title. Nvm :p

Answer (score 3):

This is coming in the next version of ECMAScript, so you might as well implement it as a shim.

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:string.prototype.repeat

From the proposal:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'repeat', {
    value: function (count) {
        var string = '' + this;
        //count = ToInteger(count);
        var result = '';
        while (--count >= 0) {
            result += string;
        }
        return result;
    },
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true
});
```

Then call `.repeat()` from a string:

```
"x".repeat(5); // "xxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.join(JavaScript).
Array()

```
function extend(ch, times){

    return Array(times+1).join('x');
}
 extend('x', 5);
```