# Double the occurence of character in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Input String : abcd

Output String : aabbccdd

How to achieve this using Javascript if 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' are an elements of an array ..

Comment: using for loop but it;s displaying aabbcc but not dd..

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex solution:

```
"abcd".replace(/[\S\s]/g, "$&$&");
```

Array solution:

```
"abcd".split("").map(function(x){return x+x}).join("");
```

For a more generic solution of the string repetition (in the array solution), have a look at [Repeat String - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/202605/1048572).

Or do it the minimalistic way with loops:

```
var input = "abcd";
var output = "";
for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    var chr = input.charAt(i);
    for (var j=0; j<2; j++)
        output += chr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var a = "abcd";
var b = "";
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    b += a.charAt(i) + a.charAt(i);
```

Comment: Bracket notation for character access from strings is not supported in early IE versions.