# In this excerpt from javascript koans, what is the Array(foo+1) all about?

Tags: javascript

The koan is below. In my lessons, I've never seen the word "Array" just stuck into code like that. Any examples elsewhere that I can study?

```
it("should know properties that are functions act like methods", function ()
{
  var meglomaniac = {
    mastermind : "Brain",
    henchman: "Pinky",
    battleCry: function (noOfBrains)
    {
      return "They are " + this.henchman + " and the" +
      Array(noOfBrains + 1).join(" " + this.mastermind);
    }
};

var battleCry = meglomaniac.battleCry(4);
expect(FILL_ME_IN).toMatch(battleCry);
});
```

**It should know properties that are functions act like methods. It is damaging your karma.**

Expected 'Fill this value in' to match 'They are Pinky and the Brain Brain Brain Brain'.

Comment: [ECMAScript 15.4.1, The Array Constructor Called as a Function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1): "When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new Array object. Thus the function call `Array(...)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(...)` with the same arguments."

Comment: See also point #5 in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9033306/1233508). It's a little muddied by the `NaN` conversions, which are irrelevant in this case, but it explains the trick and provides links to the standard where this behaviour is defined.

Comment: Then I have Array(5).join(" " + "Brain");   and this still doesn't output anything I would recognize...

Comment: OK - reading point #5. Looks promising...

Comment: it's just a cheap string repeater...

Comment: and a completely new one to me, apparently - thanks

Comment: Check out [String repeat in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript) maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, `Array(noOfBrains  + 1)` creates a new array of length five (well, given that noOfBrains is passed in as 4), in which every element is undefined:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Then, the join operation takes a string (" Brain"), and places a copy of it between each element of the array.  (A more common use of join is something like `array.join(", ")` which comma-separates an array)

So we essentially have:

```
undefined + " Brain" + undefined + " Brain" + undefined + " Brain"+ undefined + " Brain" + undefined
```

Which becomes " Brain Brain Brain Brain", since the undefined's are ignored by join.

Comment: Actually the point is that there are no items at all, but the length is 5. Only when you're accessing them they will yield `undefined`, but it's a *sparse array* without elements.

Comment: This is some crazy stuff to put in a Koan. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi Ah; I wasn't aware that there was a distinction between "each element is undefined" and "the array has no elements".  Seems like a bit of a philosophical point, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: This koan blew my head up too. I was expecting Brain Brain Brain Brain Brain - the join threw me :-@

Answer (score 1):

According to [ECMAScript 15.4.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1), `Array(...)` acts just like `new Array(...)`:

> When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new Array object. Thus the function call `Array(...)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(...)` with the same arguments.

According to [ES 15.4.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.2), the single-argument form `new Array(len)` creates an empty array with the `length` property set to the value of the argument. So, `Array(noOfBrains + 1)` creates an empty array of size `noOfBrains + 1`.

According to [ES 15.4.4.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5), `.join(separator)` loops over the array for the value of the array's `length` (step 10). It builds a string by concatenating values from the array, joined by the separator value passed as an argument to `join`. According to step 8 and step 10.c, `undefined` array values are rendered as the empty string by `.join`.

Since the array you just initialized is empty, *all* of its values are `undefined`. Therefore, `.join` joins a list of the empty strings with the separator string "`Brain`".