# appendTo, multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a string within a variable:

```
var dot = '<div class="dot"></div>'
```

And I am trying to append it to some HTML, multiple times:

```
var number = 3; // this has come from an $('img').length; could be any number

$(dot * number).appendTo('.m-slide-ctrl');
```

The above obviously does not work, but I'm not sure how to approach something so simple. The number of times I would like the string to be written, would be dependent on the number of images (so using .length)

Any help would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/VE75U/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a for loop

```
for (var i=0;i<number;i++)
{
    $(dot).appendTo('.m-slide-ctrl');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/VE75U/3/)

Answer (score 1):

without a loop, appending only once

```
$(Array(number+1).join("<div class='dot'></div>")).appendTo('.m-slide-ctrl');
```

Comment: In case someone like me didn't understand what this means, here's more explanation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript)

Comment: That's not a jQuery object so it doesn't have `appendTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slides = $('.m-slide img');        // Images in gallery
var n = slides.length;                 // count images
var dots = '';                         // HTML string

for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    dots += '<div class="dot"></div>'; // Create buttons
}
$('.m-slide-ctrl').append( dots );     // Append them
                                       // outside the loop. Faster!
```

there's no reason to force jQuery to lookup your DOM several times for the same element, and for every iteration `.append()` to that element some HTML, if all of that can be done **only once** outside the loop. Makes sense? Also, the native for loop is faster than any other jQuery loop method.

Comment: How come I only outside the loop?

Comment: @tmyie I don't get your question... Anyway, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/VE75U/8/ note also that I removed the initial `dot` from your HTML cause we don't need it anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that poorly. How come I shouldn't append inside a loop?

Comment: @tmyie added all the reasons that might interest you in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well if it comes from `$('img').length`, you could just do something like:

```
var $dotDivProto = $('<div class="dot"></div>');

$('.m-slide-ctrl').append($('img').map(function () {
    return $dotDivProto.clone();
});
```

Or simply parsing every time:

```
$('.m-slide-ctrl').append($('img').map(function () {
    return $('<div class="dot"></div>');
});
```