# Append same number of <li> as the value of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

In my case i have a mysql database with some content from a page. I have function on a page to add more `<li>` to the database, basically it just add 1 to the number in database.

On another page i would like to display the list, how do i add the same number of `<li>`as the number of a variable made by the php?

```
var number_of_items = 6; // Printet by the php

$('.list_container').append('<li></li>'); // 6 times
```

I then want to append 6 times or what wver the number is.

How do i do this?

Comment: using a `for` loop...

Comment: add a String.prototype method `repeat()` , as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript , so the code becomes `.append('<li></li>'.repeat(6))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a neat little hack using [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
$('.list_container').append(new Array(number_of_items + 1).join('<li></li>'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8CaRP/)

Comment: Master can you explain a little bit your code?..please..please `new Array(number_of_items + 1).join('<li></li>')`

Comment: @Pilot we create an empty array of `x + 1` nodes, then when we call join using on that array the empty array will be joined by the passed separator which will result in a string which is repeated x times

Comment: Nice soultion, i really like it :)
Is there a way to give each `<li>` its own id? like id="1", id="2" etc? not need it to, but if there is an easy way it would be cool.

Comment: @Legarndary not if you are using this method.... it can be used only if the string is the same

Comment: if you want that then you can create an array and then push all the `li` as strings with the desired attributes at the end you can join them and append

Comment: Ok, but thanks for the awnser, i will research for on the id thing :)

Comment: So i figured the id thing out, its here if anyone need it :)
http://jsfiddle.net/9Nvm9/

Comment: @Legarndary that is a costlier way of doing it... a cheaper way is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Nvm9/1/

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks agen mate really helped lot.

Comment: Why do we need to use `number_of_items + 1` here? I thought `number_of_items` value is already `6`?

Comment: @Felix when you join an array the separator will be repeated n-1 times not n times

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for(i=0;i<number_of_items;i++)
{
  $('.list_container').append('<li></li>');
}
```

Comment: didn't downvoted, but this is awful for the performance. You call jQuery, access the list and call the append method `number_of_times` times

Comment: The var statement should never be left out unless the desired effect is to affect the outer scope. http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var html = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   html.push('<li></li>');
}

$(".list_container").append( html.join('') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the easiest way.

```
for(var i=1; i <= number_of_items; i++)
{
  $('.list_container').append('<li></li>');
}
```

Comment: Awful for the performance. You call jQuery, access the list and call the `append` method `number_of_times` times

Answer (score 0):

A for loop it's the simplest approach:

```
for(var i = 0; i < number_of_items; i++)
    $('.list_container').append('<li></li>');
```

By the way, you have a lot of options, for example while loops and array joining.
Take a look to other answers

Comment: It's not best approach because your are calling here `append()` method  for each number_of_items. Better would be to call it only once ;)