# Insert selectable white spaces that will copy

Tags: jquery, html, css, whitespace

I'm rendering to html a large block of code with various levels of indenting that I want people to be able to copy into a text editor, with the indenting preserved.

Currently I have lots of   characters in the code, which is very messy, and makes it hard to maintain. I'd rather do it via css, using the ::before operator, but all the solutions I've tried have been problematic.

If I insert \00a0 characters before the element using :before, the whitespace is displayed by the browser, but won't copy out into a text editor.

If I use 'pre', the whitespaces in the source are preserved, it makes the rendered html too dependent on the structure of the source code - i.e. if there are divs in the source, it adds extra lines in the rendered code, plus I have to worry about whitespaces and new lines in the source code etc., which is a problem when I reformat the code in the editor, which I have to do quite often to keep it clean (it's fairly dynamic).

So basically I need some css classes that will give me varying levels of indentation, without having to add   or actual whitespace in the source, which will also copy from the browser into a text file.

Comment: Why don't you just have the code indented right off the bat?

Comment: it's dynamic, it's bound to a knockout viewmodel, and it needs to be delineated with divs, spans etc.

Comment: Would you be apposed to a jQuery solution?

Comment: I don't see how any of that rules out indenting it in the source.

Comment: Nit, it's just as messy & unreliable using indenting in the source as it is using &nbsp; all over the place - the code is updated regularly & it would be a pain making sure all the spaces were correct in between other inline tags. and as mentioned, the editor itself adds further complexity.

Comment: Brian, jQuery would be fine yep, I'm already using some jQuery anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below adds however many tabs the class indicates, `class-4` produces 4 tabs and then prepends that number of tabs into the element containing the class - [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/h642v964/) it works line by line.

**HTML**

```
<p class="tab-1">1 tab indentations</p>
<p class="tab-2">2 tab indentations</p>
<p class="tab-3">3 tab indentations</p>
<p class="tab-4">4 tab indentations</p>
```

**JS**

```
var indentElements = $('[class*="tab-"]');

$.each(indentElements, function(index) {
   var indentAmount = parseInt(this.className.split('-')[1]);
   var indentation = new Array(indentAmount + 1).join('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
   this.innerHTML = indentation + this.innerHTML
});
```

**Output**

```
    1 tab indentations

        2 tab indentations

            3 tab indentations

                4 tab indentations
```

**Steps:**

1. Select all elements with a class containing `tab-`
2. Loop over them
3. Split the class name on `-` and get index `1` (the number that follows `-`)
4. Create an array with the above number of indexes and join 4 non breaking spaces with it (creates tabs)
5. Set the HTML of that element to its current HTML content plus the multiplied `;nbsp`s

**Reference**

- I got step #4 from Peter Bailey at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202627/1342440) - cool trick.

Comment: Nice idea using class names, I tried to make this flexible so you can indent infinitely

Comment: Nice one Brian, that's perfect, thanks. bit bizarre that we have to do it programmatically, but hey, whaddyagonnnado.

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it. There aren't any selectable spaces with any CSS solutions Ive thought of. So why not programmatically add them :) Cheers.

Comment: quick question - I've moved the javascript into a separate file, and referenced it (& jquery) in my html, but the tab-1 class is not applying - chrome is telling me $ is not defined. do I have to change that to something else?

when I inspect the element that is supposed to have tab-1 applied, it is not showing an an applied class.

Comment: `$` is jQuery, make sure it is loaded and if it is, make sure it is loaded before this code. If it isn't this code's dependency on jQuery will cause that error. Afterwards if it is loading properly but still causing an issue.. place code within `$(document).ready(function(){ .. })` to insure the dom and all of the elements are loaded before performing any operations on them

Comment: thanks - I'm using knockout.js as well, which loads on dom ready, but may be in some sort of race condition with jQuery, I'll see what I can sort out.

Comment: Any other console errors? Just clarifying `<script src="jquery.js">` and after comes `<script src="tab-solution.js">`?

Comment: aha! yes I had jquery loading after your script. doh! all working now, thanks.

Comment: Ok I can comfortably part with this little code now knowing its in working condition :) take care