# match numbers without a prefix

Tags: javascript, regex, prefix

I need help with regular expression.

Using **javascript** I am going through each line of a text file and I want to replace any match of **[0-9]{6,9}** with a '*', but, I don't want to replace numbers with prefix **100**. So, a number like **1110022** should be replaced (matched), but **1004567** should not (no match).

I need a single expression that will do the trick (just the matching part). I can’t use ^ or $ because the number can appear in the middle of the line.

I have tried **(?!100)[0-9]{6,9}**, but it doesn't work.

**More examples:**

> Don't match: 10012345
>
> Match: 1045677
>
> Don't match:
>
> 1004567
>
> Don't match: num="10034567" test
>
> Match just the middle number in the line: num="10048876"  1200476, 1008888

Thanks

Comment: Replace with a single `*`, or replace each digit inside that number with `*`?

Comment: You probably want to add word boundaries such as `\b(?!100)\d{6,9}\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a **leading** word boundary to check if a number **starts with** some specific digit sequence:

```
\b(?!100)\d{6,9}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH7lW4/2)

Here, the `100` is checked right after a word boundary, not *inside* a number.

If you need to replace the matches with just a single asterisk, just use the `"*"` as a replacement string (see snippet right below).

```js
var re = /\b(?!100)\d{6,9}/g; 
var str = 'Don\'t match: 10012345\n\nMatch: 1045677\n\nDon\'t match:\n\n1004567\n\nDon\'t match: num="10034567" test\n\nMatch just the middle number in the line: num="10048876" 1200476, 1008888';
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = "<pre>" + str.replace(re, '*') + "</pre>";
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Or, if you need to replace each digit with `*`, you need to use a callback function inside a replace:

```js
String.prototype.repeat = function (n, d) {
    return --n ? this + (d || '') + this.repeat(n, d) : '' + this
};

var re = /\b(?!100)\d{6,9}/g; 
var str = '123456789012 \nDon\'t match: 10012345\n\nMatch: 1045677\n\nDon\'t match:\n\n1004567\n\nDon\'t match: num="10034567" test\n\nMatch just the middle number in the line: num="10048876" 1200476, 1008888';
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = "<pre>" + str.replace(re, function(m) { return "*".repeat(m.length); }) + "</pre>";
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

The `repeat` function is borrowed from [BitOfUniverse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411966/3832970).

Comment: Isn't that what you need? It is meaningless to set any legnth restrictions if you do not specify boundaries. My code handles all the test cases in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
The problem is that word boundary matches the entire number.
[0-9]{6,9} will allows me to leave the tail of the number, meaning 123456789012, will become *012, and this is what I want.

But \b[0-9]{6,9}\b will not match 123456789012.

Is there a way to avoid prefix 100 it without using word boundary?

Sorry for being so difficult.

Thanks

Comment: Just use the leading boundary then.