# JavaScript/jQuery: Replace 2nd, 3rd, etc space with &nbsp; but not the first one in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace, preg-match

How to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;` but not the first one (the first one after not a space).

As example, this string:

```
var str = "hello     how are you    doing?  "
```

should be changed to

```
"hello &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;how are you &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;doing? &nbsp;"
```

As you see the first space is preserved.

As example,

```
str.split(' ').join('&nbsp;')
```

would replace all `' '` with `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.replace(/  +/g, function(match) {
   return " " + Array(match.length).join('&nbsp;');
});
```

This uses the version of `replace` that takes a function to generate the substitution as the second parameter and replaces every occurrence of 2 or more spaces with a single space followed by the appropriate number of `&nbsp;`.

There is a `String.prototype.repeat` function but it isn't supported in IE so you might want to use an alternative way of generating the sequence of `&nbsp;` for now. `Array(match.length).join('&nbsp;')` is a short way to repeat a string taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202627/63034) to another question.

As an alternative you could use this function to perform the repeat, again taken from the [Repeat String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450113/63034) question:

```
function repeat(pattern, count) {
    if (count < 1) return '';
    var result = '';
    while (count > 1) {
        if (count & 1) result += pattern;
        count >>= 1, pattern += pattern;
    }
    return result + pattern;
}
```

---

*Notice with `Array(n).join` you don't need to subtract 1 from the length of the match to get the right number of non-breaking spaces. e.g. `Array(3).join('&nbsp;')` is `"&nbsp;&nbsp;"` but for the other approaches to generating the repeated string you will need 1 less than the length of the match.*

Answer (score 2):

This function will do it

```
function myFunction() {
            var str = "hello     how are you    doing?  ";
            var patt1 = /\s{2,}/g; 
            var result = str.replace(patt1,function(filtered){
                return " " + Array(filtered.length).join('&nbsp;')
            }));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
            console.log(result)
}
```

but you wont see any affect since I am writing to document
but if you write to the console you will definitely see the affect

edit-1
Thanks to mikej who pointed out mistake in My code, my little snippet is actually same as his. His answer is more Precise and has more information than provided here,

## [answer By mikej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41883953/7452237)

Comment: Won't that replace more than 2 spaces with a space followed by only a single `&nbsp;` rather than replacing every space *after* the first with  `&nbsp;`?

Comment: yes it will, sorry didn't  notice that, :( in that case I have to edit it. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: in that case I'll go with a  little same code as yours with credits to you, I hope you wont mind

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get basic, you can try something like below, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/6226609), and the comment by Ates Goral (separate utility function, rather than extend the base string class). Should work in all browsers:

```
var str = "some    words    here";
var first = true;
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == " " && !first) {
    str = fix(str, i, '\u00A0'); //insert unicode for &nbsp;
  } else if (str[i] == " " && first) {
    first = false;
  } else if (str[i] != " ") {
    first = true;
  }
}

function fix(s, index, character) {
  return s.substr(0, index) + character + s.substr(index+character.length);
}
```

Since strings are immutable, you have to return the whole (modified) string every time you make a change, and put it in the `str` variable.