# Alternative to positive look behind

Tags: javascript, regex

I just found that positive look behind doesn't work in older browsers and i'm stuck with this issue on IE11 i.e. **Unexpected quantifier**

> **regex:** `/(?<=\d{4})\d(?=\d{4})/g`
>
> **input:** `const string = 4444333322221111;`

```
string.replace(/(?<=\d{4})\d(?=\d{4})/g, "#");
```

> **expected outcome:** `4444########1111`

any alternative for this regex would be helpful.

Comment: const string = 4444333322221111;

Comment: do you have only digits?

Comment: Your input string looks like a payment card number. You don't need regex, you can use simple string processing functions like [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and string concatenation.

Comment: @Nina yes only digits.

Comment: @axiac currently im using substring to over come this issue.. but i wanted to know the best possible alternative for this regex.

Comment: `String.substring()` seems better than regex to me. The code is easier to understand (and it could also be faster but this is probably not your concern.)

Comment: Asad, when asked for clarification it is generally best to edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained and readers should not be expected to read all comments to understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If your string only consists of digits** you really need no regex, all you need is a couple of string manipulation methods:

```js
// Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5450113/3832970, count will always be positive here
function strRepeat(pattern, count) {
    var result = '';
    while (count > 1) {
        if (count & 1) result += pattern;
        count >>= 1, pattern += pattern;
    }
    return result + pattern;
};

var string = "4444333322221111";
console.log(
    string.substring(0,4) + strRepeat("#", string.length-8) + string.slice(-4)
)
```

**If you need to mask digits enclosed with four digits on either side in a longer string** you may use:

```js
function strRepeat(pattern, count) {
    var result = '';
    while (count > 1) {
        if (count & 1) result += pattern;
        count >>= 1, pattern += pattern;
    }
    return result + pattern;
};

var string = "111109876543210000 abc 1234012345678904321";
console.log(
  string.replace(/\d{9,}/g, function(match) { 
     return match.substr(0,4) + strRepeat("#", match.length-8) + match.slice(-4); 
  })
)
```

Here,

- `/\d{9,}/g` matches **all** occurrences of nine or more digits
- `function(match) {...}` -  a callback method that takes the regex match and you may manipulate the output here
- `match.substr(0,4) + "#".repeat(match.length-8) + match.slice(-4)` - concats the first 4 digits, then the digits that need to be replaced with `#` are appended, and then the remaining 4 digits are added.

If you want, you may make the regex pattern with [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), it will make the callback method a bit smaller, but will make the regex longer:

```js
function strRepeat(pattern, count) {
    var result = '';
    while (count > 1) {
        if (count & 1) result += pattern;
        count >>= 1, pattern += pattern;
    }
    return result + pattern;
};

var string = "111109876543210000 abc 1234012345678904321";
console.log(
  string.replace(/(\d{4})(\d+)(\d{4})/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) { 
     return $1 + strRepeat("#", $2.length-8) + $3; 
  })
)
```

Here, the `(\d{4})(\d+)(\d{4})` pattern will capture 4 digits into Group 1 (`$1`), then 1+ digits will be captured into Group 2 (`$2`) and then 4 digits will be captured into Group 3 (`$3`).

Comment: ie has no repeat.

Comment: @NinaScholz Glad you mentioned that, I added a fix and tested the solutions in IE, they all work there now.

Answer (score -1):

You could take a function and the index and replace either with digit for the first four digits or with `#`.

```js
var string = '4444333322221111';

console.log(string.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, function (v, i) { return i < 4 ? v : '#'; }));
```

Update with sliced strings.

```js
var string = '4444333322221111',
    result =
        string.slice(0, 4) +
        string.slice(4, -4).replace(/./g, '#') +
        string.slice(-4);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, right, but it looks like, that op has only digits in the string.

Comment: @Nina best solution for me so far.

Answer (score -1):

Your input string looks like a payment card number. You don't need regex, you can use simple string processing functions like [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) and string concatenation.

For example:

```js
const str = '1111222233334444';
const masked = str.substring(0, 4) + 
   '#'.repeat(str.length - 8) + 
   str.substring(str.length - 4)
console.log(masked);
```

A regex solution doesn't need to use lookups:

```js
const str = '1111222233334444';
const masked = str.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d*)(\d{4})$/,
  `$1${"#".repeat(str.length - 8)}$3`);
console.log(masked);
```

Comment: Already using this approach because that regex wouldn't work on IE11