# Can modern javascript create an array of X number of things? (like `map` but on a number rather than an array)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript, lit

Given a number `x` , What's the nicest way of saying give me `x` number of a given string, object, whatever, and put them all in an array.

Ideally they'd have access to their index and that's about it.

I know I can create an array and push to that in a for loop (with `i < x;`) but I'd like it cleaner, and native, please.

This kind of syntax:

```
const arrayOfDivs = numberOfDivs.repeat(idx => html`<div id=${idx}></div>`;

// numberOfDivs == 3
arrayOfDivs == [
  '<div id=${0}></div>' , 
  '<div id=${1}></div>' ,
  '<div id=${2}></div>'   
]
```

And if there's no way like this, what do other people use, and can someone ask javascript to invent it?

I do a for loop and push to an array usually, but I remember creating a `[0,1,2,3,4]` array from the number before and `.map`ing from that, bad times!

Thanks

Comment: `const arr = new Array(x).fill(0).map((_, idx) => html\`<div id=${idx}></div>\`)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat String - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript)

Comment: [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) allows as second argument a mapper function ... ``Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, idx) => html`<div id="${ idx }"></div>`)``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> like `map`

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?retiredLocale=uk) has a very similar API to `map`. You could supply it with a number that goes to `.length` property of the first argument:

```
function createSeveral<Item>(count: number, itemFactory: () => Item): Item[] {
  return Array.from({ length: count }, itemFactory) as Item[];
}
```

So, for your case, you could use it like this:

```
Array.from({ length: numberOfDivs }, (_, i) => html`<div id=${i}></div>`)
```

Comment: By the way, some time in the past I've published (as a joke) an npm package called `iterable-numbers` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/iterable-numbers), which allows doing `Array.from(5)`. This might be useful in your case (although, mutating prototypes of builtin objets is a bad idea).

Comment: Yeah i like this thanks. It could do with being _ever so slightly_ simpler but this is the best i've seen 

Comment: I like your npm lol, obviously thinking on the same tracks, i don't like using things like that though that change core behavior

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can create an array containing elements 1 to n using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`Array.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) (which you could then `.map` as you mentioned):

```js
const arr = [...Array(10).keys()];
// arr => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you want the same object repeated n times, you can use [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```js
const arr = Array(5).fill('x');
// arr => ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```